# How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use the `filter` in angular and want to filter for multiple values, if it has either one of the values then it should be displayed.

I have  for example this structure:

An object `movie` which has the property `genres` and I want to filter for `Action` and `Comedy`.

I know I can do `filter:({genres: 'Action'} || {genres: 'Comedy'})`, but what to do if I want to filter it dynamically. E.g. `filter: variableX`

How do I set `variableX` in the `$scope`, when I have an array of the genres I have to filter?

I could construct it as a string and then do an `eval()` but I don't want to use eval()...

Comment: are you sure that `filter:({genres: 'Action'} || {genres: 'Comedy'})` even works? it doesn't in `angular 1.3.16`.

Comment: same for 1.4.8 ! it's just does not work ^^

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I would just create a custom filter.  They are not that hard.

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).
  filter('bygenre', function() {
    return function(movies,genres) {
      var out = [];
      // Filter logic here, adding matches to the out var.
      return out;
    }
  });
```

#### template:

```
<h1>Movies</h1>

<div ng-init="movies = [
          {title:'Man on the Moon', genre:'action'},
          {title:'Meet the Robinsons', genre:'family'},
          {title:'Sphere', genre:'action'}
       ];" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="genrefilters.action" />Action
<br />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="genrefilters.family" />Family
<br />{{genrefilters.action}}::{{genrefilters.family}}
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="movie in movies | bygenre:genrefilters">{{movie.title}}: {{movie.genre}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit** here is the link: [Creating Angular Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters)

*UPDATE*:  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xesued/Bw77D/7/) that has an exact demo of my suggestion.

Comment: so then in the out I return the movie objects that I want to display?

Comment: Sorry it took me awhile to get back.  I updated my answer with a fiddle of a concrete example.

Comment: ok, thanks, in the meantime I figured it out myself, but it will sure help someone later :)

Comment: Either i have two value such like active and inactive then how can i search seprately using this filter. we do not want to make custom filter.

Answer (score 82):

You can use a controller function to filter.

```
function MoviesCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.movies = [{name:'Shrek', genre:'Comedy'},
                     {name:'Die Hard', genre:'Action'},
                     {name:'The Godfather', genre:'Drama'}];

    $scope.selectedGenres = ['Action','Drama'];

    $scope.filterByGenres = function(movie) {
        return ($scope.selectedGenres.indexOf(movie.genre) !== -1);
    };

}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:filterByGenres">
            {{ movie.name }} {{ movie.genre }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Besides separation of concerns, is there any reason (performance wise) that this would be avoided?

Comment: javascript version if others are looking for it: `$scope.filteredMovies = $filter('filter')($scope.movies, $scope.filterByGenres);`

Answer (score 24):

Creating a custom filter might be overkill here, you can just pass in a custom comparator, if you have the multiples values like:

```
$scope.selectedGenres = "Action, Drama"; 

$scope.containsComparator = function(expected, actual){  
  return actual.indexOf(expected) > -1;
};
```

then in the filter:

```
filter:{name:selectedGenres}:containsComparator
```

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @chrismarx What would the `ng-model` be in the view file to link up to the described filter? (sorry, still learning here) -- I like the simplicity of your answer and trying to get it work but not sure how to label my `<input>`'s `ng-model`. :)

Comment: you need to read this - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 18):

Here is the implementation of custom filter, which will filter the data using array of values.It will support multiple key object  with both array and single value of keys. As mentioned inangularJS API [AngularJS filter Doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) supports multiple key filter with single value, but below custom filter will support same feature as angularJS and also supports array of values and combination of both array and single value of keys.Please find the code snippet below,

```
myApp.filter('filterMultiple',['$filter',function ($filter) {
return function (items, keyObj) {
    var filterObj = {
        data:items,
        filteredData:[],
        applyFilter : function(obj,key){
            var fData = [];
            if (this.filteredData.length == 0)
                this.filteredData = this.data;
            if (obj){
                var fObj = {};
                if (!angular.isArray(obj)){
                    fObj[key] = obj;
                    fData = fData.concat($filter('filter')(this.filteredData,fObj));
                } else if (angular.isArray(obj)){
                    if (obj.length > 0){
                        for (var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                            if (angular.isDefined(obj[i])){
                                fObj[key] = obj[i];
                                fData = fData.concat($filter('filter')(this.filteredData,fObj));    
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                if (fData.length > 0){
                    this.filteredData = fData;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    if (keyObj){
        angular.forEach(keyObj,function(obj,key){
            filterObj.applyFilter(obj,key);
        });
    }
    return filterObj.filteredData;
}
}]);
```

**Usage:**

```
arrayOfObjectswithKeys | filterMultiple:{key1:['value1','value2','value3',...etc],key2:'value4',key3:[value5,value6,...etc]}
```

Here is a fiddle example with implementation of above **"filterMutiple"** custom filter.
[:::Fiddle Example:::](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmalkumar_86/9F89Q/5/)

Comment: You seem to have the correct intention but your example doesn't seem to work as expected. The output in the table seems rather inconsistent.

Comment: This does not work with JSON's with nested objects. Would've been ideal if it did. also it fires a `length property undefined` error in the console.

Comment: It is working for me but it returns all the results if it doesn't find the searched attribute in the list, how can I do to invert this behavior and return no result if the value doesn't exist in the list?

Comment: @ZakariaBelghiti if you want to return no results, then change the code:

`if (fData.length > 0){
     this.filteredData = fData;
}`

to just:

`this.filteredData = fData;`

Comment: @Gerfried I think that site actually scrapes Stackoverflow, so they stole his answer, not the other way around

Answer (score 15):

If you want to filter on Array of Objects then you can give

`filter:({genres: 'Action', key :value }.`

Individual property will be filtered by particular filter given for that property.

But if you wanted to something like filter by individual Property and filter globally for all properties then you can do something like this.

```js
<tr ng-repeat="supp in $data | filter : filterObject |  filter : search">
```

Where "filterObject" is an object for searching an individual property and "Search" will search in every property globally.

~Atul

Comment: This worked well for me and was a better solution than others suggesting offloading the filtering to a function as AngularJS does partial text matches when filtering on strings.

Answer (score 9):

I've spent some time on it and thanks to @chrismarx, I saw that angular's default `filterFilter` allows you to pass your own comparator. Here's the edited comparator for multiple values:

```
  function hasCustomToString(obj) {
        return angular.isFunction(obj.toString) && obj.toString !== Object.prototype.toString;
  }
  var comparator = function (actual, expected) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(actual)) {
      // No substring matching against `undefined`
      return false;
    }
    if ((actual === null) || (expected === null)) {
      // No substring matching against `null`; only match against `null`
      return actual === expected;
    }
    // I edited this to check if not array
    if ((angular.isObject(expected) && !angular.isArray(expected)) || (angular.isObject(actual) && !hasCustomToString(actual))) {
      // Should not compare primitives against objects, unless they have custom `toString` method
      return false;
    }
    // This is where magic happens
    actual = angular.lowercase('' + actual);
    if (angular.isArray(expected)) {
      var match = false;
      expected.forEach(function (e) {
        e = angular.lowercase('' + e);
        if (actual.indexOf(e) !== -1) {
          match = true;
        }
      });
      return match;
    } else {
      expected = angular.lowercase('' + expected);
      return actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1;
    }
  };
```

And if we want to make a custom filter for DRY:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('filterWithOr', function ($filter) {
      var comparator = function (actual, expected) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(actual)) {
          // No substring matching against `undefined`
          return false;
        }
        if ((actual === null) || (expected === null)) {
          // No substring matching against `null`; only match against `null`
          return actual === expected;
        }
        if ((angular.isObject(expected) && !angular.isArray(expected)) || (angular.isObject(actual) && !hasCustomToString(actual))) {
          // Should not compare primitives against objects, unless they have custom `toString` method
          return false;
        }
        console.log('ACTUAL EXPECTED')
        console.log(actual)
        console.log(expected)

        actual = angular.lowercase('' + actual);
        if (angular.isArray(expected)) {
          var match = false;
          expected.forEach(function (e) {
            console.log('forEach')
            console.log(e)
            e = angular.lowercase('' + e);
            if (actual.indexOf(e) !== -1) {
              match = true;
            }
          });
          return match;
        } else {
          expected = angular.lowercase('' + expected);
          return actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1;
        }
      };
      return function (array, expression) {
        return $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator);
      };
    });
```

And then we can use it anywhere we want:

```
$scope.list=[
  {name:'Jack Bauer'},
  {name:'Chuck Norris'},
  {name:'Superman'},
  {name:'Batman'},
  {name:'Spiderman'},
  {name:'Hulk'}
];


<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in list | filterWithOr:{name:['Jack','Chuck']}">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Finally here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/INHgnStQof8nT2f6tk7X?p=preview).

Note: Expected array should only contain simple objects like **String**, **Number** etc.

Comment: Thanks this helped me. To check for a single value  filterWithOr:{name:'Jack'}
If anyone need the same as me...

Answer (score 7):

you can use searchField filter of [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

**JS:**

```
$scope.users = [
 { first_name: 'Sharon', last_name: 'Melendez' },
 { first_name: 'Edmundo', last_name: 'Hepler' },
 { first_name: 'Marsha', last_name: 'Letourneau' }
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-model="search" placeholder="search by full name"/> 
<th ng-repeat="user in users | searchField: 'first_name': 'last_name' | filter: search">
  {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
</th>
<!-- so now you can search by full name -->
```

Comment: You can also use "where" of angular.filter
<tr ng-repeat="obj in collection | where:{id: 1}">
  {{ obj.name }}
</tr>

Comment: the `search` stops here.

Comment: I tried this and setup both the module in my angular app and the script in my index HTML but I'm still able to search for ALL fields, not just the one I specified :(

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `ngIf` if the situation permits:

```
<div ng-repeat="p in [
 { name: 'Justin' }, 
 { name: 'Jimi' }, 
 { name: 'Bob' }
 ]" ng-if="['Jimi', 'Bob'].indexOf(e.name) > -1">
 {{ p.name }} is cool
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 7):

The quickest solution that I've found is to use the `filterBy` filter from [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#filterby), for example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search by name or genre" ng-model="ctrl.search"/>   
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="movie in ctrl.movies | filterBy: ['name', 'genre']: ctrl.search">
    {{movie.name}} ({{movie.genre}}) - {{movie.rating}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

The upside is that [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) is a fairly popular library (~2.6k stars on GitHub) which is still actively developed and maintained, so it should be fine to add it to your project as a dependency.

Comment: By far the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
<div>{{ (collection | fitler1:args) + (collection | filter2:args) }}</div>
```

Comment: It just concatenate the arrays and don't return a union.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the implementation I fail to see how that is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you have two array, one for movie and one for genre

Just use the filter as: `filter:{genres: genres.type}`

Here genres being the array and type has value for genre

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
var m = angular.module('yourModuleName');
m.filter('advancefilter', ['$filter', function($filter){
    return function(data, text){
        var textArr = text.split(' ');
        angular.forEach(textArr, function(test){
            if(test){
                  data = $filter('filter')(data, test);
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for strings AND functionality (I know it's not the question but I searched for it and got here), maybe it can be expanded.

```
String.prototype.contains = function(str) {
  return this.indexOf(str) != -1;
};

String.prototype.containsAll = function(strArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    if (!this.contains(strArray[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

app.filter('filterMultiple', function() {
  return function(items, filterDict) {
    return items.filter(function(item) {
      for (filterKey in filterDict) {
        if (filterDict[filterKey] instanceof Array) {
          if (!item[filterKey].containsAll(filterDict[filterKey])) {
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          if (!item[filterKey].contains(filterDict[filterKey])) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    });  
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in array | filterMultiple:{key1: value1, key2:[value21, value22]}">{{x.name}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Angular Or Filter Module**

`$filter('orFilter')([{..}, {..} ...], {arg1, arg2, ...}, false)`

here is the link: https://github.com/webyonet/angular-or-filter

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation. Writing custom filter worked for me. Hope this helps!

**JS:**

```
App.filter('searchMovies', function() {
    return function (items, letter) {
        var resulsts = [];
        var itemMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if ( itemMatch.test(item.name) || itemMatch.test(item.genre)) {
                results.push(item);
            }
        }
        return results;
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="movie in movies | searchMovies:filterByGenres">
            {{ movie.name }} {{ movie.genre }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example how create filter and directive for table [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jasmin_kurtic/yat6ghjx/)

directive get list (datas) and create table with filters

```
<div ng-app="autoDrops" ng-controller="HomeController">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <ng-Multiselect array-List="datas"></ng-Multiselect>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

my pleasure if i help you

Answer (score 1):

Too late to join the party but may be it can help someone:

We can do it in two step, first filter by first property and then concatenate by second filter:

```
$scope.filterd = $filter('filter')($scope.empList, { dept: "account" });
$scope.filterd = $scope.filterd.concat($filter('filter')($scope.empList, { dept: "sales" }));
```

[See the working fiddle with multiple property filter](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11278/)

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:
Using Angular providered filter comparator parameter**

```
// declaring a comparator method
$scope.filterBy = function(actual, expected) {
    return _.contains(expected, actual); // uses underscore library contains method
};

var employees = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}, {name: 'd'}];

// filter employees with name matching with either 'a' or 'c'
var filteredEmployees = $filter('filter')(employees, {name: ['a','c']}, $scope.filterBy);
```

**OPTION 2:
Using Angular providered filter negation**

```
var employees = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}, {name: 'd'}];

// filter employees with name matching with either 'a' or 'c'
var filteredEmployees = $filter('filter')($filter('filter')(employees, {name: '!d'}), {name: '!b'});
```

Answer (score -3):

My solution

```
ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter: {'Action'} + filter: {'Comedy}"
```

Comment: checked on VS 2015, it doesn't get the syntax and it doesn't work also

Answer (score -14):

the best answer is :

```
filter:({genres: 'Action', genres: 'Comedy'}
```

Comment: Does this not just filter on 'Comedy'?

Comment: I tried this and it only filters on 'Comedy', not on 'Action'.