# AngularJS multiple filter with custom filter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to filter the list with multiple filters + with a custom filter function.

The original working jsfiddle example is http://jsfiddle.net/ed9A2/1/ but now I want to change the way age are being filter.

I want to add a custom filter so that **age** it filter based on two input value which is **min_age** and **max_age** , (between age) .

After looking into doc. I found people having similar questions and a user Mark Rajcok answer http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter#comment-648569667 looks good and should be working.  But I am having problem applying it into my code which mainly seems to because I have other multiple filters.

My tried and NOT working fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/ed9A2/20/

A copy paste of my NOT working codes are here

View

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainController">
<table class="fancyTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Player id</th>
        <th>Player name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input ng-model="player_id" /></td>
        <td><input ng-model="player_name" /></td>
        <td>
            Min Age:<input ng-model="min_age" />
            Max Age:<input ng-model="max_age" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter:{id: player_id, name:player_name, age:ageFilter}">
        <td>{{player.id}}</td>
        <td>{{player.name}}</td>
        <td>{{player.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
function MainController($scope) {

$scope.player_id = "";
$scope.player_name = "";
$scope.player_age = "";
$scope.min_age = 0;
$scope.max_age = 999999999;

$scope.ageFilter = function(player) {
    return ( player > $scope.min_age && player.age < $scope.max_age);
}

$scope.players = [
        {"name": "Rod Laver",
            "id": "rod",
            "date": "1938/8/9",
            "imageUrl": "img/rod-laver.gif",
            "age": 75},
        {"name": "Boris Becker", 
            "id": "borix",
            "date": "1967/11/22",
            "imageUrl": "img/boris-becker.gif",
            "age": 45},
        {"name": "John McEnroe",
            "id": "mcenroe",
            "date": "1959/2/16",
            "imageUrl": "img/john-mc-enroe.gif",
            "age": 54},
        {"name": "Rafa Nadal",
            "id": "nadal",
            "date": "1986/5/24",
            "imageUrl": "img/ndl.jpg",
            "age": 27}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter:{id: player_id, name:player_name} | filter:ageFilter">

$scope.ageFilter = function (player) {
    return (player.age > $scope.min_age && player.age < $scope.max_age);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Hope below answer in this link will help,
[Multiple Value Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs/21169596#21169596)

And take a look into the fiddle with example

```
arrayOfObjectswithKeys | filterMultiple:{key1:['value1','value2','value3',...etc],key2:'value4',key3:[value5,value6,...etc]}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmalkumar_86/9F89Q/4/)

Comment: this one returns all the result if it doesn't find the searched attribute in the list, how can I do to invert this behavior and return no result if the value doesn't exist in the list?

Answer (score 0):

In view file (HTML or EJS)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.itemList  | filter: myFilter > </div>
```

and In Controller

```
$scope.myFilter = function(item) {
return (item.propertyA === 'value' || item.propertyA === 'value');
}
```