# Angular filter with minimum and maximum values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm having some trouble getting angular to properly filter my results. I'm attempting to use a custom filter that gets arguments from a minimum input and a maximum input.

/index.html

```
<input ng-model="minHorsepower">
<input ng-model="maxHorsepower">
...
tr(ng-repeat="plane in planes | filter:horsepowerFilter")
```

/controllers.js

```
//Horsepower filter
$scope.horsepowerFilter = function(plane) {
  var ret = true;

  if($scope.minHorsepower && $scope.minHorsepower > plane.horsepower) {
    ret = false;
  }

  if($scope.maxHorsepower && $scope.maxHorsepower < plane.horsepower) {
    ret = false;
  }

  return ret;
};

$scope.planes = [
  {
      'make' : 'Piper',
      'model' : 'Arrow',
      'modelNumber' : 'PA-28R-180',
      'horsepower' : '180',
      'gear' : 'retractable',
  },
  {
      'make' : 'Piper',
      'model' : 'Arrow',
      'modelNumber' : 'PA-28R-200',
      'horsepower' : '200',
      'gear' : 'retractable',
  }
];
```

It works INITIALLY when I set $scope.minHorsepower/$scope.maxHorsepower in controllers.js, but only initially, not when I put something else in the `<input>`s. Furthermore, it prefills the inputs AND filters the results. It just doesn't work properly when I change the value of the inputs.

I've referenced this Stack Overflow thread, but I can't find any material differences in our code... [AngularJS multiple filter with custom filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: usually this kind of questions get quicky answered when you provide jsfiddle or plnkr

Comment: I suggest you to make sure using numbers.  In your code you are comparing strings and it would not work as you expect.  e.g. You can add zero ('horsepower + 0') to convert string into a number.

Comment: I made a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/GnF6IE?p=preview but there is no problem filter it. Can you post your plnkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't pinpoint exactly the problem you're having with your code. However, I think I have created [a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/s6CWCL9enYIpGhBrel4K) that (I believe) works as intended.

Apart from parsing the inputs with parseFloat, the logic seems to be the same. Not parsing the inputs to a numeric form shouldn't "break" it, but will possibly make it behave strangely ("9" > "10" for example).

Anyway, hopefully you can pull out the useful pieces and get it working.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure the model values are numbers and not strings, change the `type` for your inputs to be `number`.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="minHorsepower" />
<input type="number" ng-model="maxHorsepower" />
```

Also, make sure your model values are numbers and not strings.

Alternatively, you can run everything through `parseFloat(...)` in your filter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only send to the filter a function, it doesn't know to watch for any value changes, and thus to trigger the filter function when it happens.

When you define a filter as {{ filter_expression | filter : filterValue}},  angular watches the filterValue and triggers the filter function when it changes.

To achieve what you need you can define your own filter:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('range', function(){
    return function(items, property, min, max) {
      return items.filter(function(item){
        return item[property] >= min && item[property] <= max;
      });
    };
  });
```

and call it like this:

```
ng-repeat="plane in planes | range : 'horsepower' : minHorsepower : maxHorsepower"
```