# What is the best way to get the length of all true values for a $scope object in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this object and would like to get the length of all keys, where the value is "true" and then display the length in an HTML file:

```
$scope.foobar = [
  {"a": false},
  {"b": false},
  {"c": true},
  {"d": true}
]
```

After some research I found I could use a custom filter:

```
{{ (foobar | trueValues).length }}
```

1. How should the custom filter look like?
2. Would that be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Array.prototype.filter()** and get the **first property** of each element.

```
function isTrue(obj) {
  return obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]] == true;
}
var trueArray= $scope.foobar.filter(isTrue);

console.log(trueArray.length);
```

or you can include the callback function without declaring it

```
    var len = $scope.foobar.filter(function(obj) {
        return  obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]] == true;
    }).length;
    console.log(len);
```

In Angular:

```
$scope.trueLen = function() {
    return $scope.foobar.filter(function(obj) {
        return  obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]] == true;
    }).length;
}
```

Comment: Where do I define the function? In the controller or filter?

Comment: How can I move that to a custom filter so that can reuse the function?

Comment: thats another question, but give me your email I'll give you an example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function