# How to filter inside ng-repeater something filtered by custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have custom filter:

```
errorReporter.filter('customDateFilter', function () {
    return function (input) {
        var input1 = parseInt(input.substring(6)); //da makne onaj /Date  početak
        var jsDate = new Date(input1);
        var day = jsDate.getDate();
        var month = jsDate.getMonth();
        var year = jsDate.getFullYear();
        return day.toString() + "." + (month + 1).toString() + "." + year.toString();
    };
});
```

I also have :

```
 <tr class="animate-repeat"  ng-repeat="error in latestErrors| orderBy:predicate:reverse|
 filter:{ TimeUtc :SearchTimeUtc}">

            <td >{{error.TimeUtc | customDateFilter}}</td>
        </tr>
     And somewhere I have filter input :
 <th><input type="text" ng-model="SearchTimeUtc" /></th>
```

Problem is that with input I filter "TimeUtc" and not  "TimeUtc | customDateFilter".

Example, I have TimeUtc /Date/5869454458/, and TimeUtc | customDateFilter returns 12.07.2014. If I type 2014 inside input it does not filter. If I type 5869 I get row filtered.

UPDATE:
I made this filter:
  errorReporter.filter('SearchTimeUtcFilter', function () {

```
return function (input) {
    var input1 = parseInt(input.substring(6)); //da makne onaj /Date  početak
    var jsDate = new Date(input1);
    var day = jsDate.getDate();
    var month = jsDate.getMonth();
    var year = jsDate.getFullYear();
    var datum = day.toString() + "." + (month + 1).toString() + "." + year.toString();
    $log.info("why doesn't log?");
    if (datum.indexOf($scope.SearchTimeUtc) > -1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

});
and inside ng-repeat:

```
 <tr class="animate-repeat"  ng-repeat="error in latestErrors| orderBy:predicate:reverse|
 filter:{ TimeUtc :SearchTimeUtcFilter}">
```

Still nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try chaining filters? Basically, the output of one filter becomes the input of the next.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Show me the code. What to write inside ng-repeat filter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function

Comment: I have created a small fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/ckQ2U/

One filter deliberately capitalises every word.
Second filter matches only if the value in the textbox matches the capitalised word (i.e. output of filter) - Like your modified date... If you provide fiddles, we can play with that, but I think this example should help you out with your issue. Hope  this helps