# Defining a controller method as a custom filter does not work in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, filter, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement a custom filter using a controller method in AngularJs bundled with Ionic.

```
<div class="list">
    <a class="item item-icon-right" data-ng-repeat="d in filtered_documents = (data.documents | filter:filterDocuments )">
        {{ d.name }}
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
$scope.filterDocuments = function(doc) {
    return true;
}
$scope.data.documents = [{name: "doc1"}, {name: "doc2"}];
```

I'm sure of my setup since I can put a break point in `filterDocuments` method and see it run. But the list is always empty and nothing's ever listed!

I'm using AngularJS v1.3.6 bundled within Ionic, v1.0.0-beta.14.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your filter function for your module, like this:

```
angular.module('yourModule', []).filter('filterDocuments', function() {
    return function(doc) {
        return true;
    };
});
```

Comment: That's the proper way to define a `filter`. But I'm more interested in solutions like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function#answer-header

Answer (score 0):

You cant use $scope methods or controller methods as filter you need to use a custom angular filter, and define it with a sintax like this (similar to the controller sintax but as a filter)

```
yourApp.filter('filterDocuments', function(){
    return function(array) {
         //your logic for the array here
         return filtered_array //return the array modified by your code
    }
})
```

and the in your template html

```
<div class="list">
    <a class="item item-icon-right" data-ng-repeat="d in data.documents | filterDocuments">
        {{ d.name }}
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```