# Angularjs filter by more than one value from the scope data

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Currently I have this in my controller:

```
$scope.showPostsByTags = function (tag) {

    $scope.selectedTag = tag

};
```

And in my view I have this in my ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="post in postsData| filter: selectedTag"
```

The "selectedTag" property contains one string only. I am getting my tag from one menu with links:

```
ng-click="showPostsByTags(tag)"
```

Which is alright!

I am trying to archieve multiple tags and I want to display the posts not only by one string, but by multiple.

For example my scope property would contain many values pushed in array and **$scope.selectedTag** would return `'world', 'sports', 'strike'`.
Unfortunately I cannot filter my posts by multiple values from array/object

I guess I need something to replace my current `"filter: selectedTag"` but I cannot figure it out. I found solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function) but they solve different problems. Can you give me some guidance? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why doesn't the solution linked in your question work? It seems good, you just need to change the condition. Or you can make your custom filter and pass the values your want to filter and the array from which you show the data.

Comment: When  $scope.selectedTags = 'cuba'; everything works. I need to show posts when  $scope.selectedTags = ['world', 'cuba']

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote quickly a custom filter for you:

```
app.filter('multipleTags', function($filter){
  return function multipleTags (items, predicates) {
    angular.forEach(predicates, function(predicate){
      items = $filter('filter')(items, predicate)
      //if you want to match exact tag you can use exact match filter
      //items = $filter('filter')(items, predicate, true)
    })
    return items;
  }
})
```

if you go to this working plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhnuM0WW3GZS5QLxK98t?p=preview you will see it in action

if you specify i.e. single letters like b,e it will select only element that contains both,you can obviously make it works with whole words

Comment: When $scope.selectedTags = 'cuba'; everything works. I need to show posts when $scope.selectedTags = ['world', 'cuba']

Comment: ohhh, if you already have it as an array then remove the line with `.split` and it will work, you can also replace `predicate.trim()` with just `predicate`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

http://plnkr.co/edit/6GwqaS7xVLZapeADSRUw?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tags = ['apple', 'orange'];
  $scope.selectedFilter = function(val) {
    var found = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.tags, function(tag) {
      if (val.indexOf(tag) !== -1) {
        found = true;
      }
    })
    return found;
  }
  $scope.data = [
    'scrambled eggs',
    'green eggs and ham',
    'apples and oranges',
    'apple pie',
    'orange juice',
    'eggs, oranges, apples'
  ];
});
```

Template:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p>selected: {{tags}}</p>
    <p ng-repeat="d in data | filter:selectedFilter">{{d}}</p>
  </body>
```

This will select only the strings appearing in tags. Hooking that in I leave to you.