# Angular 3 filters (inputs and checkboxes)

Tags: angularjs, filter

I need some help.

screenshot: https://monosnap.com/file/VxAdq975FVT6QHkECfxlFyHgGd3sAn

I have 3 filters on top: rooms, size and price. How to filter table results, when something typing in the filter fields?

**UPDATE**

```
$scope.$watch( '[min_size, max_size]', function(val) {
        $scope.filterBySizeRange();
    });

    $scope.filterBySizeRange = function() {
        $scope.filteredSizes = [];

        angular.forEach($scope.apps, function(items) {
            if (items.size >= $scope.min_size
                && items.size <= $scope.max_size) {
                $scope.filteredSizes.push(items);
            }

            if (!$scope.min_size 
                && !$scope.max_size) {
                $scope.filteredSizes.push(items);
            };
        });
    };
```

**UPDATE 3**
Here is my solution, that works with single or multiple range input fields

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15055/)

Comment: It would be better if you provide some code

Comment: Can you provide the code that creates the table?

Comment: If you googled the same you would get this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function

Comment: @Vineet I have another issue

Comment: Then why don't you share with us ?

Comment: @Vineet I mean that my issue different that you posted in the link later

Comment: @Satif Alright. Have you cleared your point now ?

Comment: @Vineet no. i don't found any solution now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Min/max size filter
$scope.sizeFilter = function(app){
    if (!$scope.min_size && !$scope.max_size) {
        return app;
    } else if(!$scope.max_size){
        return (app.size >= $scope.min_size);
    } else if(!$scope.min_size){
        return (app.size <= $scope.max_size);
    } else {
        return (app.size >= $scope.min_size && app.size <= $scope.max_size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `$watchGroup`.

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['min_size', 'max_size'], function(val) {
        $scope.filterBySizeRange();
    });

    $scope.filterBySizeRange = function() {
        $scope.filteredSizes = [];

        angular.forEach($scope.apps, function(items) {
            if (items.size >= $scope.min_size
                && items.size <= $scope.max_size) {
                $scope.filteredSizes.push(items);
            }

            if (!$scope.min_size 
                && !$scope.max_size) {
                $scope.filteredSizes.push(items);
            };
        });
    };
```

Anyway I believe that it would be better to create your own filter function

// template

```
<div ng-repeat="item in apps|sizefilter:min_size:max_size">
```

// filter

```
app.filter('sizefilter', function() {
  return function(collection, minSize, maxSize) {

 var items = collection.slice(0, collection.length -1);
        var i =0, len = items.length
        for (; i < len;) {
            if (items.size < minSize && items.size > maxSize) {
                items.splice(i, 1);
            } else {
              i++;
            }
        }
        return items;
    });



  };
});
```