# Multiple filter implementation in one table using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I need to implement multiple filter option in one table's multiple column using angular.js. Suppose I applied one filter on one column and filtered the value from table.I have also another filter in 2 column of the table here I need based on first filtered value when user will select any value from second filter option the values will be again filtered accordingly.I am explaining my code below.

> subject.html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
<colgroup>
<col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>
<select style="width:100%; border:none; font-weight:bold;" ng-options="sub.name for sub in noCourse track by sub.value" ng-model="search">
<option value="">Course Name</option>
</select>
</th>
<th>
<select style="width:100%; border:none; font-weight:bold;" ng-options="sem.name for sem in noSemestersTable track by sem.value" ng-model="search1">
<option value="">Semester</option>
</select>
</th>
<th>Subject Name</th>
<th>Short Name</th>
<th>Edit</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="sub in subjectData | filter:search.value" >
<td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
<td>{{sub.course_name}}</td>
<td>{{sub.semester}}</td>
<td>{{sub.subject_name}}</td>
<td >{{sub.short_name}}</td>
<td>
<a href='#subject?s_i={{sub.subject_id}}'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit'>  
</a>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here I am able to filter the values from table using the first column(`i.e-Course Name`).Here i have another select option (`i.e-Semester`) in next column.When user will select any value from this list the values should again filtered which is based on the first filtered values. Simply i can say applying the second filter option the values will display only from the first filter value not from whole table.

Comment: Instead of doing `<tr ng-repeat="sub in subjectData | filter:search.value" >` you can filter the subjectData based on the selection of courseName and Semester in the controller itself. You could trigger the filter by watching the models of both the select elements.

Comment: Can you write your answer ?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with sample data? It will be easier than creating the entire controller based on your html.

Comment: You can take any example of some array of data.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function

Comment: I have already visited this site.It not exactly same as my issue.