# filtering ng repeat based multiple properties with AND operation in Angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following array of json objects in my angularjs application.

```
$scope.clients = [ {  
  "code": "FREG",
  "name": "Feranget",
  "role": "employee" 
},
{  
  "code": "CRTE",
  "name": "Crenart",
  "role": "admin" 
},
{  
  "code": "DERT",
  "name": "Derta",
  "role": "admin" 
} ]
```

I have search form where I can enter code in the put text box, to search in this clients based on code. So I have applied a filter in ng repeat on the property `code`, which is working fine.

```
<tbody ng-if="clientSearch.clientCode">
    <tr ng-repeat="client in clients | filter:{ code: clientSearch.clientCode }">
</tbody>
```

Now I need to support the search form with two more input fields, `name` and `role`  having models as `clientSearch.clientName` and `clientSearch.clieRole`. `clientSearch.clientName` should be filtered on `name`  property of the object and `clientSearch.clieRole`should be filtered on `role` property of the object with `AND` operation based on the input fileds, i.e., if  `code` and `role` are entered in the respective input boxes then the clients should be filter out based on `code` and `role`  but `name` filter should be ignored because it is empty. If `name` is also entered in the input box then the clients should be filtered based on `code` and `role` and `name`. Essentially empty fields should be ignored for filter and all non empty fields should be applied in filtering clients list with `AND` operation.

Here I have used the condition  `<tbody ng-if="clientSearch.clientCode">` so that by default clients list won't appear when input filed `clientCode` is empty and appear only when the entered text matches the search criteria. This feature needs to be maintained across all the three input fields `clientSearch.clientName`, `clientSearch.clieRole` and `clientSearch.clientCode`. When I replaced it with  `<tbody ng-if="clientSearch">`, it is not working by default all the client list is appearing

In my controller I have input models are initialized as shown below:

$scope.clientSearch = {
                clientCode :'',
                clientName : '',
                clientRole : ''
        }

Can any one help me to solve this filtering problem in simple and genralized manner.

Comment: Check out this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass multiple fields in filter

```
<tbody ng-if="(clientSearch.clientCode !=null && clientSearch.clientCode !='') || (clientSearch.clientName !=null && clientSearch.clientName !='') || (clientSearch.clientRole !=null && clientSearch.clientRole !='')">
    <tr ng-repeat="client in clients | filter:{ code: clientSearch.clientCode, name: clientSearch.clientName}">
</tbody>
```

If you pass multiple fields to filter then `AND` operation will be used while filtering.

See Example : [**http://plnkr.co/edit/kozaU39E74yqjZCpgDqM?p=preview**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kozaU39E74yqjZCpgDqM?p=preview)

Comment: vvk,  your simple solution is  working fine but the problem is occurring with ng-if="clientSearch.clientCode". The search results should  appear only if input fields are non empty and are matching relevant search text. I have changed it to  ng-if="clientSearch" but by default all list is appearing which I do not want. May be I have not emphasised this point in my question, but I need this also to be worked correctly.

Comment: No need to be both either one of three is non empty and matching filter criteria then only it should display the client list. I tried with <tbody ng-if="clientSearch.clientCode || clientSearch.clientName ||  clientSearch.clientRole ">  but by default all the list is appearing even though all the three input fields are empty.

Comment: In the controller I have initialized my search models are $scope.clientSearch = {
          clientCode :'',
          clientName : '',
                clientRole : ''
        }

Answer (score 1):

Write a customized filter,

```
app.filter('filterbyNameRoleCode', function(){
      return function(items,name,role,code){
         var filtered = [];

         for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

         if (itmes[i].name.indexof(name)> -1 && itmes[i].role.indexof(role)> -1 && itmes[i].code.indexof(code)> -1 ) {
          filtered.push(items[i]);
        };
      };
    } 
    return filtered;

});
```

then use it

```
<tbody ng-if="show(clientSearch)">
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients | filterbyNameRoleCode:clientSearch.clientName:clientSearch.clientRole:clientSearch.clientCode }">
</tbody>
```

Comment: Jerry, I have edited my question to consider ng-if condition too. Can you please include that feature also in your solution.

Comment: You need to write a method to check to show your table or not. You probably need to set $scope.clientSearch.clientName and other to "" as the default in your controller. It would avoid undefined issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant way to do that (without using multiple filters or conditions in your HTML), will be creating a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters):

```
yourApp.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function (input, obj) {
    if (/* test that input complies with your conditions obj */) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients | customFilter:clientSearch">
```