# AngularJS how to have multiple $filter in a controller?

Tags: angularjs

The leftValue array contains JSON information such as { name: 'John', gender: 'male' }
I am trying to filter information by both name and gender in a search bar. For now, the filter only filtered by name. How can I filter by both name and gender?

```
scope.leftValue = $filter('filter')( leftValue, {
                    'name': text
                    })
```

What I have tried

```
scope.leftValue = $filter('filter')( leftValue, {
                    'name': text,
                    'gender': text,
                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your getting a little mixed up. You can specify an object map like your second example. This is what the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) state about it when you do.

> Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on
>   objects contained by array. For example `{name:"M", phone:"1"}`
>   predicate will return an array of items which have property name
>   containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A special property
>   name `$` can be used (as in `{$:"text"}`) to accept a match against any
>   property of the object or its nested object properties. That's
>   equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described
>   above. The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !.
>   For example `{name: "!M"}` predicate will return an array of items which
>   have property name not containing `"M"`.

The important thing to take away here is the second sentence and the `and`. Meaning in order for a match the string, in your case `text`, has to match ALL properties specified in your map.

Searching for just `male` wont match if the name is only `John` for example. But searching for `ma` would return the following record:

```
{
   name: 'mark',
   gender: 'male'
}
```

Just for FYI you can also search by object map through the view but it has the same limitations.

That being said it is possible to use the `$` wildcard giving it a comma separated list of properties. This will do an `or` match over any of the properties.

```
{
   $: 'name,gender'
}
```

The catch here is all properties will have the same value checked against them.

Here's a [fiddle showing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) them in action.

The other answers sum up quite well the alternatives, just felt they were lacking in explaining what was happening and the reasons behind it.

Comment: Hi the link is not a fiddle link

Comment: I tried ''$': text, and it will check for all properties. I also tried '$: "name,gender"': text but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: @zainu I'm not at my computer but when I am ill update the fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chain of filters.

```
 var result1 = $filter('filter')( leftValue, {'name': text })
  var result2 = $filter('filter')( result1 , {'gender': text })
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. But can chain of filters check for 'name' OR 'gender'?

Answer (score 0):

I think better we do it in html.

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter:{id: player_id, name:player_name} | filter:ageFilter">

$scope.ageFilter = function (player) {
    return (player.age > $scope.min_age && player.age < $scope.max_age);
}
```

You can check the way they do in this link:
[AngularJS multiple filter with custom filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function)

Comment: Please post the useful parts of links in the body of your answer. If the link goes down your answer will be of no use. I realize its a link to another SO question but if that question was ever deleted. Plus its just a good habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

i appreciate you said in the controller, but just to give you options you can have it all done in your HTML.

```
{{yourJSONLinkedToScope | filter: name | filter: gender}}
```

where name and gender are ng-models from the input boxes.