# angular filter is not working on table if I only input one letter

Tags: angularjs, filter

This is the way how I do filter on a table

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in sptable.data.data | filter: searchTable">
```

and the `searchTable` is ng-modeled to an input.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SEARCH INVOICES" ng-model="searchTable">
```

`sptable.data.data` is an array of objects. one of the objects is

```
{"customerWatched":false,"invoiceID":"00c9511b-24b9-4190-a90a-8abf2fe9f4a0","amountDue":"0.00","referenceNumber":"O721-001","amount":"35.75","contact":{"watched":false,"contactName":"Net Connect","contactId":"bym568b799d81934d3","errorMessage":"","redirectURL":null}
```

it has more than 100 objects in the array, so cannot list them all.

Unfortunately, if I input one letter, the table does not change anything. But if I input two letters or more, then it works.

what would be the reason?

---

update: the whole object is too large that I only display part of object in the table. and when I input some letters, it would even search on the hidden part of the object. how to filter on the displayed items of the object only?

Comment: Can you put the code you use for the searchTable input ?

Comment: modified @daan.desmedt

Comment: Can you provide us the JavaScript code of your `sptable.data.data` object?

Comment: @Mistalis, list one of the objects

Comment: I know the reason now. I only display part of the object in the table. when I input some letters, it would even search on the items which are not  displayed in the table. anybody knows how to filter on the items which are displayed and ignore the ones are hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular's filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) filter looks in the whole object for your `searchTable` value.

> All strings or objects with string properties in array that match this
>   string will be returned. This also applies to nested object
>   properties.

When you put only one letter, it probably don't change the table because this letter is present in at least one attribute of each line of `sptable.data.data`.

If you prefer, you can filter on a specific attribute of your array (for example `invoiceID`):

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in sptable.data.data | filter: {invoiceID: searchTable}">
```

Comment: one more question. what if I want to filter on 5 items of the whole object?

Comment: @Benjamin : You can use the same synthax with: `filter: {invoiceId: searchTable1, amountDue: searchTable2}`. You can also add a specific filter in a function as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function).