# Angular.Js dynamically updating an input with sum of other 3 inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a table with 6 rows and 4 columns (the fourth one is a Total:  which should be a sum of the above 3 columns). Basically what I want to do is calculate the sum of each column and show the total number in the fourth column. My table is generated using ng-repeat.

Something like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Input1:</td>
            <td ng-repeat="collection in collections">
             <input type="text" ng-model="collection.row1">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Input2:</td>
            <td ng-repeat="collection in collections">
             <input type="text" ng-model="collection.row2">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Input3:</td>
            <td ng-repeat="collection in collections">
             <input type="text" ng-model="collection.row3">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sum:</td>
            <td ng-repeat="collection in collections" ng-model="collection.total">
             {{collection.total}}
            </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

"collections" from ng-repeat would be an array with 6 objects which I'm getting from an API using a GET method and storing my data in a $scope.

"Total" row with ng-model is coming from backend with the calculus already done but I need a way to show it on client as it is updating dynamically.

I've tried $watch and $watchCollection and also ng-change but I can't find a way to make it work. In my controller I used a for to go through my array of objects and tried to sum every [i] position but that didn't work.

Is there another solution for my issue?

Here is what I tried in my controller:

```
$scope.collections = [];

$scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.collections[i].length; i++){
        var myItems= $scope.collections[i];
        total = (myItems.row1+ myItems.row2+ myItems.row3);
    }
    return total;
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried...

Comment: Provide a fiddle plz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply do it in the template?

```
<td>{{collection.row1 + collection.row2 + collection.row3}}</td>
```

Also, there should not be an ng-model unless it is an `<input>`. That's probably where your main error is. Ng-model will try to set the value inside the `<td>`'s, and so the angular template (`{{X}}`) and ng-model are competing for the display value inside the `<td></td>` in your code given

Comment: Hmmm. I tried this and it will concatenate the 3 values not sum them.

Comment: {{ (collection.row1 * 1) + (collection.row2 * 1) + (collection.row3 * 1) }} worked for me but now I have another problem. My input types are "text" but my inputs reffers to times (hh:mm) and obviously it can't sum them up like this.

Comment: change the type to `<input type='datetime-local' >`

Comment: your question was about summing the 3 inputs, if I've helped please upvote/accept in exchange for my time.. if you have different issue ask another question

Comment: I can't upvote with less than 15 reputation earned, my account is new. :) But i've accepted your answer.

Comment: And input type datetime-local is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this seems potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18792039/3100494 .. I'd say you need to do something like `{{ toText( toDate(collection.row1)  + toDate(collection.row2) + toDate(collection.row3) ) }}` - where you create the $scope.toText and $scope.toDate functions as you need, if you are also looking at doing type conversion before summing

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate the total in the back-end

$scope.CalculatedTotal = Some Value;

so you can call in the last row:

```
        <td>Sum:</td>
        <td ng-repeat="collection in collections" ng-model="collection.total">
         {{CalculatedTotal}}
        </td>
```

or store the CalculatedTotal in to the object

```
currentCollection.Total = CalculatedTotal;
```

something like that

Comment: I can display my calculated value from the backend but I want to see instead of {{CalculatedTotal}} a total sum of all other inputs as I edit them. Something like a $scope.$watch('collection.total', function() { $scope.total = $scope.collection[i].row1 + $scope.collection[i].row2 + $scope.collection[i].row3; });

Comment: use data-ng-model instead of ng-model and put your data-ng-model in the parent repeat