# How to filter data with more than one condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some alarm data in my list and i want to filter them based on some condition like if there are more than one alarm of type pull_Alarm and emergency_alarm in same location then give priority to emergency alarm.

```
Here is my list:
[
    {
        alarmType:"Normal_ALARM"
        location:"Ward5"
        severity:"URGENT"
    },
    {
        alarmType:"Emergency_Alarm
        location:"Ward1"
        severity:"URGENT"
    },
    {
        alarmType:"PULL_Alarm"
        location:"Ward1"
        severity:"NORMAL"
    }
]
```

What i want a list after filter should be only

```
[
  {
    alarmType:"Normal_ALARM"
    location:"Ward5"
    severity:"URGENT"
  },
  {
    alarmType:"Emergency_Alarm
    location:"Ward1"
    severity:"URGENT"
  }
]
```

Can someone suggest me how i can apply filter on these condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function

Answer (score 0):

Create one filter with switch cases or add if else conditions.

```
.filter("alarmFilter", function () {
    // write condition what ever you want to add
});
```

And apply this filter to your expression where you want to apply condition.

Answer (score 0):

Write filter

```
$scope.filter1 = function(item)
    {
        return (item.severity == 'URGENT');
    };
```

and then use it

```
<div ng-repeat="item in object| filter:filter1">{{item.alarmType}}</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8866/

Comment: How i can filter this inside controller rather than use to filter records in html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter, as below.

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).
filter('byAlarmCount', function() {
  return function(alarms, severity) {
    var items = {
      severity: severity,
      out = []
    };
    angular.forEach(alarms, function(v, k)) {
        if (this.severity[v.severity] === true) {
          this.out.push(v);
        }
      }
    return items.out;
  }
});
```

DOM as below

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="alarm in list | byAlarmCount:severityFilter">{{alarm.location}: {{alarm.alarmType}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do some complex filtering then its better to look at some third party JS libraries like lodash (https://lodash.com/) or Underscore (http://underscorejs.org/).

These provide a wide range of utilities that can be used for filtering, mapping and other common utility functions.

For example for this current scenario you can use _.where / _.filter from underscorejs.

```
var filteredAlarms = _.where(<YOUR LIST>, { severity: NORMAL, alarmType: ...});
```

Comment: You can use _.where(...) inside your controller, you only need the underscore.js file already injected. There are ways to make this as a service so that you get seemless working inside your controllers, my favorite one is this, https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/how-to-use-underscore-in-your-angularjs-controllers