# How to merge two filters (AND operation)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have two menus with options...

```
<div class="date_menu" ng-repeat="singledate in dates">
    <p>
        {{singledate}}
    <input type="radio" name="filterDateChosen" ng-model="$parent.dateFilter" ng-value="singledate">
    </p>
</div>


<div class="date_menu" ng-repeat="singledate in dates">
    <p>
        {{singledate}}
    <input type="radio" name="filterDateChosen2" ng-model="$parent.dateFilter2" ng-value="singledate">
    </p>
</div>
```

These filters work on their own, so if I use only one of them in this way, it works...

```
<div class="form-container" ng-repeat="formblock in forms | filter:dateFilter">
```

...This will filter by a chosen date value.

But what I want is for the user to choose and option from the first menu, and choose and option from the second menu, so if the user picks from menu 1 `feb 26` and in the second menu they choose `march 1`, I want the to show all formblock with either dates `march 1` or `feb 26`.

I tried the following but it does not provide the proper results...

```
<div class="form-container" ng-repeat="formblock in forms | filter:dateFilter | filter:dateFilter2">
```

How can I filter using both filters inclusively?

Comment: I think you are looking for this. [Multiple filter in angular js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Expression `{{ expression | filter1 | filter2 }}`

```
<div class="form-container" ng-repeat="formblock in forms | filter:{  datefilter | datefilter2 }">
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function).

Comment: Edited , Is that Working now?