# filter just 2 out of 3 columns angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<table> 
  <tr>
      <th>Primary Key</th>
      <th>descriptionShort</th>
      <th>descriptionLong</th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="terReason in data | filter :({descriptionLong:searchTerm}||{descriptionShort:searchTerm}  )">
      <td>terReason.primaryKey</td>
      <td>terReason.descriptionShort</td>
      <td>terReason.descriptionLong</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have this table. How can i make that the filter works only on descriptionLong or descriptionShort and not in primaryKey. 
At this time the filter works only on descriptionLong.
    [DATA sceernshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aui4m.png)

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18792135/4045532)?

Comment: yes i have seen it. i forgot to say that i want with searchTerm to search on both columns. Not with searchTerm1 or searchTerm2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is what you want:

```
<input ng-model="searchTerm">
<table> 
  <tr>
      <th>Primary Key</th>
      <th>descriptionShort</th>
      <th>descriptionLong</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="terReason in data | filter : myFilter">
        <td>{{ terReason.primaryKey }}</td>
        <td>{{ terReason.descriptionShort }}</td>
        <td>{{ terReason.descriptionLong }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$scope.data = [
{
  primaryKey: 0,
  descriptionShort: 'descriptionShort ZERO',
  descriptionLong: 'descriptionLong descriptionLong descriptionLong ZERO'
},
{
  primaryKey: 1,
  descriptionShort: 'descriptionShort ONE',
  descriptionLong: 'descriptionLong descriptionLong descriptionLong ONE'
},
{
  primaryKey: 2,
  descriptionShort: 'descriptionShort TWO',
  descriptionLong: 'descriptionLong descriptionLong descriptionLong TWO'
},
{
  primaryKey: 3,
  descriptionShort: 'descriptionShort THREE',
  descriptionLong: 'descriptionLong descriptionLong descriptionLong THREE'
}  
];

$scope.myFilter = function myFilter (value) {
  return !$scope.searchTerm || Object.keys(value).some(function (key) {
    return key !== 'primaryKey' && value[key].search($scope.searchTerm) !== -1;
  });
}
```

pluner: http://plnkr.co/edit/VMcs064WWbGraULyXQTU?p=preview
try to search by *0* or *1* - nothing displayed, it is not searching by primary key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i have to do this for every Primary key in a Millions of data, that would be to much code for this .

Comment: If i follow your answer it searches only in descriptionLong, not in descriptionShort

Comment: I will update my answer in half an hour or so (need to leave now), thanks @EndritDemaj for pointing, I will use filter function which will omit primaryKey key from its search

Comment: im going to add a screenshot of 'data' maybe im not seeing something

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr ng-repeat="terReason in data | filter :filter1 | filter :filter2  ">
      <td>terReason.primaryKey</td>
      <td>terReason.descriptionShort</td>
      <td>terReason.descriptionLong</td>
</tr>
```

Why not use multiple filters?

Comment: this way filters are *ANDED* instead of *ORED*