# AngularJS different filter method in a "ng-repeat" is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Code snippet**

```js
//controller

$scope.filterByCategory = function (wine) {
  return $scope.filter[wine.search_by_item] || noFilter($scope.filter);
};


$scope.filterByLocations = function (w) {
    var chambers_location = [];
    for(var i=0; i<w.chambers.length; i++) {
      chambers_location = w.chambers[i].chamber_location_name;
    }
    return $scope.filter[chambers_location] || noFilter($scope.filter);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- filter with checkbox options -->

<h3 class="panel-title">Location</h3>

<ul>
    <div ng-repeat="cat in getCategories()">

        <label>
            <b> <input type="checkbox" class="doctor_checkbox" ng-model="filter[cat]"/> <span ng-if="cat!=0"><% cat %></span><span ng-if="cat==0">Others</span></b>
            <span >(<% (names | filter:cat).length %>) </span>

        </label>

    </div>

</ul>

<h3 class="panel-title">Areas</h3>
<ul>
    <div ng-repeat="locations in getLocations()">
        <label>
            <b> <input type="checkbox" class="doctor_checkbox" ng-model="locations" ng-if="locations!=null"/> <span ng-if="locations!=null"><% locations %></span></b>
            <span ng-if="locations!=null">(<%(names | filter:locations).length%>) </span>

        </label>
    </div>

</ul>
      
      
<!-- ng-repeat with filtered value -->

<div class="content-area-article content-area" ng-if="w.check_subscription == 1" ng-repeat="w in filtered=(names| filter:filterByCategory | filter:filterByLocations)">
  
  <!-- codes will go here -->
  
  
</div>
```

**filterByCategory()** and **filterByLocations()** both methods are not working if called in the same **ng-repeat**.
But if I comment out any one of this method from controller it's work perfectly.

Could you please explain how to solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS multiple filter with custom filter function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function)

Answer (score 1):

Your filters for `ng-repeat` should look like this:

```
ng-repeat="w in filtered | filter: filterByCategory | filter: filterByLocations"
```

Comment: I tried this but not working till now.
Is there another way to resolve ?

Comment: Actually I used more filters like `ng-repeat="w in names|filter:query | filter:filterByCategory | filter:filterRange | filter:filterDay | filter:filterConsultancy | filter:filterBySpecialization | filter:filterByLocations" `

All are working but above those are conflicting each other

Comment: Don't you need to add `w.` here? `$scope.filter[w.chambers_location]`

Comment: `w` is a multidimensional array and I make another array which return only `chambers location`.
I just want to filer this new array

Answer (score 1):

```js
      var myapp= angular.module('myapp', []);

            myapp.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
                $scope.fdata = '';
                $scope.data = [{id: 1, fname: 'pravin'},

                    {id: 2, fname: 'nitin'},
                    {id: 3, fname: 'parag'}
                ];

                $scope.myfunction = function(){

                    return $scope.data.filter(function(item){ 
                        return (item.id.toString().indexOf($scope.fdata) > -1 || item.fname.indexOf($scope.fdata) > -1)
                    }); //end of filter
                }; //end of myfunction 
            }])
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myapp">
    <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-controller="myctrl" >
            <span></span>
            <table  >
                <tr>
                    <td >filter by Id/  Name</td>
                    <td ><input type="text" ng-model="fdata" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> Id</th>
                    <th> Name</th>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="obj in myfunction()">
                    <td>{{obj.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{obj.fname}}</td>               
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: simple way using input box for other see ex. here  http://fiddle.jshell.net/andreas_karz/rZ5rD/light/