# Apply custom filter to ng-repat at single property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I must create a custom filter to apply just to a property of my model. 
Following, the filter:

```
.filter("cpesFilter", function() {
    return function (arrayToFilter, value) {
        var output = [];

        if (value == undefined || value == "") {
            output = arrayToFilter;
        }
        else {
            angular.forEach(arrayToFilter, function (arrayItem) {

                if (arrayItem.connettivita == value) {
                    output.push(arrayItem);
                }
            });
        }

        return output;
    };
});
```

Here the HTML:

```
<tbody class="no_body_bordered"><!--  | cpesFilter:search.connettivita -->
    <tr ng-repeat="modello in cpes.modelli | filter:{ prodotto: search.prodotto, vendor: search.vendor, connettivita:cpesFilter(cpes.modelli, search.connettivita) }  " ng-click="selectModello(modello.upc)" 
        ng-class="{ selected: modello.upc === upcCpeSelezionato }" class="selectable-row">
        <td style="width:15%">{{ modello.vendor }}</td>
        <td style="width:15%">{{ modello.prodotto }}</td>
        <td style="width:20%">{{ modello.connettivita }}</td>
        <td style="width:10%">{{ modello.voipFxs }}</td>
        <td style="width:10%">{{ modello.voip }}</td>
        <td style="width:10%">{{ modello.wifi ? "SI" : "NO" }}</td>
        <td style="width:10%">{{ modello.vpnS2s ? "SI" : "NO" }}</td>
        <td style="width:10%">{{ modello.vpnServer ? "SI" : "NO" }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In this way I've never gone inside the filter. But if I apply the filter in this way, it works:

```
<tr ng-repeat="modello in cpes.modelli | cpesFilter:search.connettivita">
```

But, it's not what i am looking for. How can I correct the line to work?

Thank you

Comment: try to apply multiple filters :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function
<tr ng-repeat="modello in cpes.modelli | filter:{ prodotto: search.prodotto, vendor: search.vendor} | cpesFilter:search.connettivita">

Comment: It has workeb, but I hat to change also the filter... I had to pass the `arrayToFilter` as input