# Anuglar js filter deep objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am stuck in a situation where i have to find the data using filter in ng-repeat

Situation :

Data is an array of **objects** with **name** and **status** and status has property **a**

now want to filter objects having property **status.a** as **started** and **in progress**

I have tried multiple solution

**Sol1**:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {status :{a:'Not Started'},status: {a:'In Progress'}}
```

returns result : **status.a of In Progress only**

Sol2:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {status :{a:'Not Started' , a:'In Progress'}}">
    {{ item.name }}
</p>
```

returns same result : **status.a of In Progress only**

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>List 1</h1>
    <ul>
            <li class="clearfix">
              <label>
                 <input ng-model="tracks.ns"
                        ng-true-value="'Not Started'"
                        ng-false-value="''" 
                        type="checkbox">
                 Not started 
              </label>
            </li>
            <li class="clearfix">
              <label> <input ng-model="tracks.ip" ng-true-value="'In Progress'" ng-false-value="''" type="checkbox">In-progress </label>
            </li>
            <li class="clearfix">
              <label> <input ng-model="tracks.do" ng-true-value="'Done'" ng-false-value="''" type="checkbox">Done </label>
            </li>
    </ul>
    {{tracks.ns}}
    <p ng-repeat="item in filteredItems">{{ item.name }}</p>
    <h1>List 2</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {status :{a:'Not Started' , a:'In Progress'}}">{{ item.name }}</p>
</div>
```

**js**

```
    $scope.items = [{
    name: "Alvi",
    status: {
        a: 'Not Started'
    }
}, {
    name: "Krane",
    status: {
        a: 'Done'
    }
}, {
    name: "Tate",
    status: {
        a: 'In Progress'
    }
}, {
    name: "Lorus",
    status: {
        a: 'In Progress'
    }
}];
    $scope.tracks = {ns: '',ip: '',done : ''}
```

Questions:

1. Can I achieve the desire result without custom filter ?
2. If yes than how without custom filter?

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/njsoPu1LHLmNmEx6lCew?p=preview

Comment: I don't think it can be done in the ng-repeat unless you skip the filter and use ng-if, like this:      <p ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.status.a === 'Not Started' || item.status.a === 'In Progress'">{{ item.name }}</p>

Comment: Why are you opposed to using a custom filter? It is the perfect solution to your situation.

Comment: @Lex I want to use the power of angular js  filters rather than custom one

Comment: Use a custom filter. This is 100% recommended by angularjs and best practice.

Comment: @RaphaMex any blog/site for recommendations

Comment: There are many, many examples of custom filters on SO. [Here is one that shows a custom filter along with a regular filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function).

Comment: Separation of concerns is one of the important stuff in app development. Dont mix your complex business with the View which will be harder to maintain later. Keep your logic in the controller or create custom filter at the app level. Even if your requirement is available its not nice to implement that way

Answer (score 0):

Use a function in the filter expression:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filter : customFn">
            {{ item.name }} {{ item.status }}
</p>
```

JS

```
$scope.customFn = function(value, index, array) {
    console.log(value, index, array);
    if (!value) return true;
    if (value.status.a == 'Not Started') return true;
    if (value.status.a == 'In Progress') return true;
    //else
    return false;
}
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Filter Component Reference - filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/sEle9LQ8pR14EBH5J5i9?p=preview)