# Angular nested filters in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I have items to search by title(string) or tags(array of strings)

items:

```
[
  {
    title: 'My title',
    tags: ['tag1', 'other']
  },
  {
    title: 'Misc',
    tags: ['tag1', 'notag']
  }
]
```

I want one input to search in title OR tags

In my template, this works well :

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="query">
</form>

<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query:title | filter:query:tags">
    <p>{{item.title}}</p>
</li>
```

All my items are shown and if I enter text, it filter by title or tags.
ex:
I type `title`, only the first item is returned and if I type `tag1`, both are returned.

Now, I need to have an other scope with the results of that search filter.

In my controller/directive, I tryied :

```
scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($filter('filter')(scope.items, {title: scope.query}), {tags: scope.query});
```

But I don't have the same results, what did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using the filter incorrectly in your HTML. If you look at the [filter documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/filter/filter), you will see that it expects an expression and a comparator. So, as of right now, in the HTML, you are passing `query` as the expression and `title` or `tags` as the comparator, both of which are undefined.

Because you are passing a string as the expression,

> The string is evaluated as an expression and the resulting value is
>   used for substring match against the contents of the array. All
>   strings or objects with string properties in array that contain this
>   string will be returned.

In other words, all of the properties in each item are searched for the query. This is why it seems to be filtering by `title` and/or `tags`.

Then, in your controller, you are passing an object as the expression. This makes it so it does in fact only return items where the given attribute matches the given value. However, since you're invoking it twice, you are filtering your items where BOTH `title` and `tags` match your `query`.

There are two ways to go about fixing this.

If you don't mind searching all fields for `query`, you can do this as follows. In your HTML, replace with

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">
```

and in your controller, replace with

```
$scope.filteredItems = $filter("filter")($scope.items, $scope.query);
```

However, if you'd like to only search `title` and `tags`, it's a lot more complicated. See this post on how to create a custom filter that searches multiple fields:

[How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs)

Comment: But how about if the OP _only_ wants to filter on `title` and `tags`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) and yes, I want to filter only on title and tags. Is there any way to keep the default angular filter with only specific values?

Comment: Unfortunately, the default angular filter only lets you filter on ALL values you specify, not some.