# filter ng-repeat using various array or object items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok I have a ng-repeat:

```
<div id="scrolltwo" class="animate-repeat panel" ng-repeat="items in arrayfull |filter:filtertype ">
```

and in filtertype i have:

```
[[0] => "Typeone", [1] => "Typetwo" ]
```

how do i get the filter to iterate across the whole array and match results that match the values?

UPDATE with custom filter:

```
<div id="scrolltwo" class="animate-repeat panel" ng-repeat="items in arrayfull | array | filter:matchaccnttypes(accnttypes)">
```

Array filter which works:

```
.filter('array', function() {
  return function(items) {
    console.log(items);
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
   return filtered;
  };
})
```

matchaccountypes which doesn't!:

```
                    $scope.matchaccnttypes = function matchaccnttypes(query) {
                        return function(items) {
                                return items.Organtype.match(query); 
                            angular.forEach($scope.accnttypes, function(value, key){
                                console.log(key + ': ' + value);
                             });
                        }
                    };
```

it just returns the last value passed into the $scope.accntypes array which is my sample array above..

Comment: Do you mean for an item to pass if it matches *one* of the array values? Or *all* of them?

Comment: One of the values in the array..

Comment: If your arrayfull = [1,2,3,4] and filtertype =[1,2] . what is the result that you are expecting?

Comment: i expect the result to be NEWarrayfull =  [1,2]

Comment: A custom filter is the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: @marcKline thats whaty i thought I'm half way there but failing, I'll post the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom filter with the help of underscoreJS. Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/fnZL7/)**.

```
app.filter('arrayFilter', function() {
    return function(input, filterType) {
         return  _.intersection(input,filterType);
    };
});
```

Without UnderscoreJS

```
app.filter('arrayFilter', function() {
    return function(input, filterType) {
       var filterdArray =[];
         angular.forEach(input, function(inputValue, key){
             angular.forEach(filterType, function(filterTypeValue, key){
                 if(inputValue==filterTypeValue){
                     filterdArray.push(inputValue);
                 }
     });

     });
     return filterdArray;

    };
});
```

and `ng-repeat` should be used in the following way.

```
ng-repeat="array in arrayfull | arrayFilter : filterType"
```

Comment: and without underscore?

Comment: how about if it was two objects?

Comment: you mean the filterType is two object? like [[1,3],[4,6]] ?

Comment: I mean what is filter type was a {} as was arrayfull

Comment: In that case an object comparison have to be made.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52618/discussion-between-vimes1984-and-user2380695)

Comment: ok this works but i get a Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '2' in all