# Filter in ng-options not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have an object that maps IDs to their objects.  I would like to display the list of these object and use a filter, but I cannot get it to work.  Specifically, I'm trying to prevent object with ID 2 from appearing in the options  Here's what I've got:
http://jsfiddle.net/9d2Za/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
    Unfiltered:
    <select ng-model="selectedBidType"
        ng-options="bidType.id as bidType.label for (bidTypeID, bidType) in bidTypes">

    </select>
    <br>
    Filtered:
    <select ng-model="selectedBidType"
        ng-options="bidType.id as bidType.label for (bidTypeID, bidType) in bidTypes | filter:{id: '!2'}">

    </select>
</div>
```

Please note: I cannot change the structure of the `bidTypes` object in whatever fix we come up with.  Here's my AngularJS:

```
function ctrl($scope)
{
    $scope.selectedBidType = 1;
    // Bid type objects are indexed by ID for fast lookup (this cannot be changed in solution)
    $scope.bidTypes = {
        1: {id: 1, label: "Buy"},
        2: {id: 2, label: "Sell"},
        3: {id: 3, label: "Missing"}
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As described by the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), the `filter` filter only accepts an array as first parameter, not an object. In such cases, I personally use a custom filter to make the transformation:

```
myModule.filter(
        'objectToArray',
        [
            function ()
            {
                return function (object)
                {
                    var array = [];
                    angular.forEach(object, function (element)
                    {
                        array.push(element);
                    });

                    return array;
                };
            }
        ]
    )
;
```

And then, in the template:

```
 <select ng-options="… in bidTypes | objectToArray | filter:{id:'!2'}">
```

Comment: If I want to remove two elements How can I specify in the filter??I tried  |filter:{id:'!2' '!3'} but not working

Comment: @MANOJ [This question may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs).