# How do you filter JSON based on which checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple JSON object in my javascript, and I want to filter it when a button is clicked.

I looked around and found this. So far I have this:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(a) {
        for(meal in $scope.mealTypes){
            var t = $scope.mealTypes[meal];
            if(t.on && a.type.indexOf(t.name) > -1){
                return true;   
            }               
        }
    };

  $scope.mealTypes = {Breakfast: false, mainMeal:false};
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="Breakfast" value="Breakfast" data-ng-model="mealTypes.breakfast">

<input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="mainmeal" value="Main Meal" data-ng-model="mealTypes.mainMeal">
```

Then I aim to iterate the array and display the checked button pressed (I wish to display the names):

```
<span ng-repeat="reciepe in reciepes | filter:search" id="filtertag" name="hello">{{ reciepe.type }}
                <span id="filtertagRemove"> 
                <a href="google.com">remove</a>
                </span>
</span>
```

Json:

```
$scope.reciepes = 
  [
    {
      "type": "Breakfast",
      "title": "Chili con carne",
      "description": "A spicy and fragrant chili with ground beef, kidney beans, tomatoes, onions and garlic. Best served over rice with a dollop of sour cream and some cheese on top.",
      "ratings": 4,
      "ingredients": 
          [
            {
              "vegetable": "40ml"
            }
          ],
      "method": 
          [
            {
              "1": "In a medium sized stock pot, heat the oil over medium heat. Saute onions, chile peppers andgarlic until soft."
            }
          ]
    },

    {
      "type": "Main Meal",
      "title": "Main Meal",
      "description": "A spicy and fragrant chili with ground beef, kidney beans, tomatoes, onions and garlic. Best served over rice with a dollop of sour cream and some cheese on top.",
      "ratings": 4,
      "ingredients": 
        [
            {
              "vegetable": "40ml"
            }
        ],
      "method": 
        [

            {
              "1": "In a medium sized stock pot, heat the oil over medium heat. Saute onions, chile peppers andgarlic until soft."
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Basically I aim to display the checkbox value on a div when it's pressed and filter the array. How should I do this?

Comment: I wonder where is button? n whats your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use the checkboxes to flag your data model items as selected or not selected, and display them based on this flag. Here's an example I made:

```
<label ng-repeat="meal in recipes">{{meal.type}}
        <input id="checkBox" ng-model="meal.selected"  type="checkbox"/>
    </label>


    <div ng-repeat='meal in recipes' ng-show="meal.selected">
        <h3>{{meal.type}}</h3>
        <p>{{meal.description}}</p>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zgavf/5/

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869436/1716542) suits your question. Basically, it uses OR operation to filter out on clicking checkboxes. You need to modify this answer to adapt your data and purpose,

Core code is:

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).
  filter('bygenre', function() {
    return function(movies,genres) {
      var out = [];
      // Filter logic here, adding matches to the out var.
      return out;
    }
  });
```

Here is the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xesued/Bw77D/7/) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

First thing they should be radio button instead of checkboxes.

```
 <div ng-controller="HelloCntl" ng-init="type='Breakfast'">
Breakfast
 <input id="radio" type="radio" data-ng-model="type" ng-value="'Breakfast'"/>
 Main Meal
<input id="radio" type="radio" data-ng-model="type" ng-value="'Main Meal'"/>
 <div ng-repeat="rec in reciepes| filter : type">
     <div> {{rec}}</div>
 </div>
```

Try above hope this will work.