# AngularJS multiple filter for the same key

Tags: angularjs

My question is very simple. I have an ngRepeat with filter, I want to apply many filters for the same key. For example, I want to filter all the players with names ' john ' and ' mickle '.

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter:{NAME:['john','mickle']}">
        <td>{{player.id}}</td>
        <td>{{player.name}}</td>
        <td>{{player.age}}</td>
 </tr>
```

For achieving this I have done like below, but it's not working.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter:query">
                <td>{{player.id}}</td>
                <td>{{player.name}}</td>
                <td>{{player.age}}</td>
    </tr>
```

And in the controller I wrote,

```
var filter_input_dict = {"NAME":['john','mickle']}
$scope.query = filter_input_dict;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ng-repeat is missing a closing quote. Try changing "NAME" to "name" so that the case matches.

Comment: also please have look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: its not about the case match..i have updated my question please have a look

Comment: fix the unterminated string?

Comment: i have changed to single quotes..but no use the result is still same. I have updated the question too

Comment: javascript properties are case-sensitive, you can't use "NAME" and 'name' and expect your filter to work. Also, passing an array as a property value, and expecting it to filter with a logical "OR" is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following way.

$scope.query = function(arr){return ['john','mickle'].indexOf(arr.name) > -1;};