# Filter angular-ui typeahead autocomplete for more than one field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have a [snippet in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lt0Spn784PdoGsP6pJI4?p=preview).
I am try to filter result for two fields(in OR condition)

```
typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue,country:$viewValue}"
```

instead of current

```
typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}"
```

the condition applied as AND term, but I need OR term

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: Is you issue solved? Have you tried the answer I provided below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom filter:

```
angular.module('plunker')
  .filter('custom', function () {
    return function(inputArray, args) {
      var outputArray = [];
      // Filtering logic below:
      angular.forEach(inputArray, function (item) {
        if (item.name.indexOf(args.viewValue) !== -1 || item.country.indexOf(args.viewValue) !== -1) {
          outputArray.push(item);
        }
      });
      return outputArray;
    };
  });
```

See the working plunker here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4s2ZxOokiXw9uMG5r75

You can find doc for creating custom filters here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters