# Angular filters: search two categories of many

Tags: angularjs, search, filter

I've been trying to think of a way to search products by Name AND Producer, not just one of them. Looking through documentation, I found how to tie search filter to one kind, but not multiple (not all).
For example, if I have a list of persons with names, surnames and phone numbers, I'd like to be able to search through only name and surname in one input field. If I type in my search field, this model will look for a match in Name and Producer. How do I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!
My code above.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Search</label>
    <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name or producer" autofocus>
    <label>
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Producer</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Packaging</td>
        <td>Is it alcoholic?</td>
        <td>Volume</td>
        <td>Popularity</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Added</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in products | filter:query | orderBy: drinkOrder:direction">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.producer}}</td>
        <td><img ng-src="img/{{item.picture}}.jpg" alt="{{item.name}}" height="50px"></td>
        <td>{{item.type}}</td>
        <td>{{item.packaging}}</td>
        <td>{{item.alko}}</td>
        <td>{{item.volume}}</td>
        <td>{{item.popularity}}</td>
        <td>{{item.country}}</td>
        <td>{{item.added}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS file app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/lynda/ithouse/js/data.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data;
        $scope.drinkOrder = 'popularity';       
    });
}]);
```

JSON file:

```
[
{
    "name"       : "Sample Beer", 
    "producer"   : "Great Beer Producer",
    "picture"    : "two",
    "type"       : "beer",
    "packaging"  : "glass",
    "alko"       : "yes",
    "volume"     : "1",
    "popularity" : "1",
    "country"    : "Latvia",
    "added"      : "2015-01-03",
    "price"      : "20,40"
},{
    "name"       : "Sample Cider",
    "producer"   : "Great Cider Producer",
    "picture"    : "one",
    "type"       : "cider",
    "packaging"  : "plastic",
    "alko"       : "yes",
    "volume"     : "2",
    "popularity" : "3",
    "country"    : "Estonia",
    "added"      : "2015-01-03",
    "price"      : "20,40"
},{
    "name"       : "Best Wine",
    "producer"   : "Wine for You",
    "picture"    : "eight",
    "type"       : "wine",
    "packaging"  : "glass",
    "alko"       : "yes",
    "volume"     : "2",
    "popularity" : "5",
    "country"    : "Lithuania",
    "added"      : "2015-01-03",
    "price"      : "20,40"
},{
    "name"       : "Another Beer",
    "producer"   : "Beer Land",
    "picture"    : "seven",
    "type"       : "beer",
    "packaging"  : "aluminium",
    "alko"       : "no",
    "volume"     : "4",
    "popularity" : "2",
    "country"    : "Latvia",
    "added"      : "2015-05-03",
    "price"      : "21,40"
}
]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: Thnak you for that, but I guess my level in Angular is too low, so I can't figure out how to search only by name and producer with <input type="text"> :(

Comment: you don't have surname in your json .

Comment: Will edit my question, thank you. I want to be able to search for name or producer, not everything else.

Comment: ok.thats fine.you want to display the product if the search text is present in both the fields or one of the fields?

Comment: Yes. For example, if I type in "beer" and I have a product that contains this word in Name or in Producer, it will appear in search results. But if I type in something that neither Name or Producer have, nothing will appear, even though other category maybe has.

Comment: You simply can use `filter: {"name": query, "producer": query}`

Comment: It looks like I am not sure how to set it up. It doesn't print out my list at all when I do this :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/divm/5tvuxsqp/ this fiddle give you the results if the search text is present in both the fields

Comment: @RaphaelMüller  this return the product having `query` in both `name` and `producer`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom filter like below

**Filter**

```
.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(query) {
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.products, function(value, key) {
            if (value['name'] == query || value['producer'] == query)
                this.out.push(value)
        })
        return out;
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/e95n3tbb/3/)

Comment: Thank you, but the fiddle lokks like the previous with a defined Beer. Could you, please please please, edit it? Thank you!

Comment: Also: the idea is that the return is products that have query in Name OR Producer, not both.

Comment: note that it text is case sensitive ,you can add the logic to get it otherwise

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on where to look up how?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you!