# AngularJs: programmatically filter by either of 2 columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, filtering

I have the following code in my controller:

```html
$scope.filteredTransactions = $scope.invoiceTransactionsObject.transactions.concat(); // make a copy of the initial array
if ($scope.searchTerm.message)
{
    var search = $scope.searchTerm.message;
    $scope.filteredTransactions = $filter('filter')($scope.filteredTransactions, ({ message: search } || { item: search }));
}
```

I want to be able to filter by typing some value and search either in the message column or item column. According to [How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs) it should work, but it doesn't and if I type something that can be found in the message, it works, but when I type something from the item, it returns empty array.

Do you see where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** Deleted irrelevant/mistaken initial answer

Since you're applying $filter inside a JS script, and it doesn't use any of the advanced features of $filter, I'd switch over to the JS-native method of filtering an array:

```
$scope.filteredTransactions = $scope.invoiceTransactionsObject.transactions.concat(); // make a copy of the initial array
if ($scope.searchTerm.message)
{
    var search = $scope.searchTerm.message;
    $scope.filteredTransactions = $scope.filteredTransactions.filter(function (trans) {
return trans.message.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0 || trans.item.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    });
}
```

...assuming that $filter is case-insensitive and matches anywhere in the string. If that's not the functionality of $filter and/or not what you want, you'd adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: I don't have $scope.searchTerm.item at all. My search input control has the following ng-model : searchTerm.message. Originally it was just searchTerm and also had filter in the HTML and it worked fine. But then I wanted to move the filtering in the code to be done by a button. So, I want to search for whatever I type in the search control in 2 columns of my array

Comment: To be clear, I have several columns in the filteredTransactions object including message and item column. The name of the input search control should not matter, I believe. I just want the filter to be applied to either of these 2 columns and not other columns of my array.

Comment: OK, my mistake. Sorry, I don't have a solution that makes use of what you have, but I can see where the solution in the linked SO question wouldn't work when you bring it from an Angular expression (as the asker is talking about) into JS code. The "||" in your example is evaluated in JavaScript, so it just checks if { message: search } is true, which it is. The second half ({ item: search }) isn't even evaluated in that context.

Comment: If that's not clear, the unspoken assumption is that anything expression-like that appears in a binding expression in a view/template is an *Angular* expression, which is similar to JS but not the same. The asker appears to be assuming something like `<div ng-repeat="vals in someArray | filter:({genres: 'Action'} || {genres: 'Comedy'})">`. The syntax and what you can do inside JS w/filters is different, in a way I have no experience with.

Comment: I can try going back to just searching for the input, e.g. $scope.filteredTransactions = $filter('filter')($scope.filteredTransactions, search) although I'd really like to have a solution of searching in 2 of my columns and not all columns (as some are not shown in the grid).

Comment: Your updated answer works perfectly for me after I fixed mistyped toLowerCase(). Thanks again, I was thinking in that same direction but was not sure how to implement the filtering.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to do what you were trying, with $parse() or $eval(), but I don't know how to do it. Just mentioning so that anyone reading this in the future doesn't get the wrong idea;  IMO using native JS inside the controller is easier to read/maintain, so I would do it this way even if I knew how to do it the other way :)