# how to filter on multiple keys with OR condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

According to the docs,

> `{name:"M", phone:"1"}` predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" **and** property phone containing "1".

I want to implement an **or** between those keys. for example it should return the rows which have property name containing "M" **and also** the rows having phone property containing "1".

Is there any expression by which I can do that? or I'll have to implement a custom filter for the same

Comment: I think its a duplicate question. Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: I see, so looks like custom filter is the only option. I was expecting something like this to be available just by tweaking filter expression.

Answer (score 0):

you may try [array filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
list.filter(function(element){ return element.name.includes('M'); })
```

Can also try jquery

[$.grep:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

$.grep(list, function(element){ return element.name.includes('M'); })

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's too early to conclude but it looks like creating a custom filter is the solution.

Here's it is,

```
.filter('orFilter', function () {
    return function (list, filterOn) {
        var out = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
            var item = list[i];
            for (var key in filterOn) {
                var val = filterOn[key];
                if (~item[key].indexOf(val)) {
                    out.push(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
});
```

I'll wait if someone posts a better solution.