# How to do multiple filtering in angular ui-grid?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to filter a column with multiple conditions. Here's my code:

```
filters : [ 
    {
        condition : uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN,
        placeholder : 'greater than'
    },{ 
        condition : uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN,
        placeholder : 'less than'
    }
]
```

The above code will show "greater than" and "less than" the value of a particular column. I need to add 2 more conditions: something like "not between greater than and less than values".

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/co8tfDrn2EOyC5thrMwg?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

The column filter can also take functions and the function signature is

```
function(term,value,row,column){
}
```

as long as this function returns a true your row will be visible. The column filter function in your case will be this

```
 $scope.colFilter.condition = function(term,value, row, column){
      return (value>$scope.greater && value<$scope.less)
    }
```

Look at this plnkr for the greater and lesser functionality.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4HCwBdkOWGOl07XmxPKi?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Are these conditions hardcoded, or are something you want the user to be able to edit? You can do this with custom filtering as shown in the UI-Grid docs: [link](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20306%20Custom%20Filters)

And by writing a custom filter function- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs)