# AngularJS, filtered one sentence by multiples filters

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, multipleselection

Yo everyone,

I've got a little blocking on a work with AngularJS. I want to filter one sentence with two differents filters based on `<select> <option>`

Theme 1:

```
<select size="2" multiple="multiple" ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option value="value1">value1.1</option>
    <option value="value1">value1.2</option>
    <option value="value1">value1.3</option>
</select>
```

Theme 2:

```
<select size="2" multiple="multiple" ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option value="value1">value2.1</option>
    <option value="value1">value2.2</option>
    <option value="value1">value2.3</option>
</select>
```

And here you can see my ng:repeat

```
<table ng-init="allValue = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($table)); ?>;">
    <tr ng-repeat="value in allValue | filterMultiple:{valueCheck:selectedValue}">
        <td>
            <font class="title_recette">{{value.name}}</font>
            <br>
        {{value.valueCheck}}
        {{value.valueTime}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

During my search, I found this link : [How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs/21169596#21169596) which explain how filterMultiple works but which works with 3 differents selects on 3 differents values.

So. my "valueCheck" has sentences with some words and I want that it's possible to filtered these with **Theme 1 + Theme 2**. Currently, when I filter with one, I can't with the other. I can accumulate filters on themselves but not with the other.

EXEMPLE
Theme 1 option : Day, Month, Year
Theme 2 option : Happy, Sad, Tired
Sentences : One day I was happy, An other day I was sad, Work a full month is tiring

when I select *Day* + *Year* + *Sad*, I want to have :

- One *day* I was happy
- An other *day* I was *sad*

Currently if I pick in order : Day + Year + Sad, only Sad will be take for the filter and so, only 
 - An other day I was *sad*
 
will be return.

Thanks in advance for any helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have two drodowns and both are set to same [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).i.e `ng-model="selectedValue"`. So value gets overwritten. You need to set separate ng-model for those two drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not bind 2 different selects with the same model (the ones you've mentioned as Theme 1 and Theme 2).

Then probably you should take a look on using [ngOption](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of simply writing down the options yourself, the way angular manages the model being populated from html source (instead of scope defined one, or in an ng-init stance) is tricky and not always do what it supposed to do. In the end it's a mainly javascript-driven-html not the way around.

As for the filter you can simply pipe filter into another filter: 
Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in allValues | filter:sel1Value | filter:sel2Value"> ... </tr>
```

refer [general angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) functionality page for further information.