# jQuery Chosen Select not filtering my data on table with angularjs ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I had to make some changes on the webpage i'm working, before this, i had an input textfield to filter results on a table, this was the code:

```
  <p><input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="search" placeholder="Search..."></p>
```

and the code for the table was:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in someFile| filter:search | orderBy:'name'">
     <td>{{data.state + ', ' + data.city}}</td>
     <td> more data goes here etc...</td>
</tr>
```

that worked just fine, but now i need to change the input textfield for jQuery chosen **select** to get different info with multiple filters.

The code i tried is this:

```
 <select   data-placeholder="Search..." multiple class="control-group chosen-select" chosen id='sl_edo'  style="width:200px;">
            <optgroup   ng-repeat="data in someFile[0].state | orderBy:'name'" label={{data.name}}>
                <option  value=""> </option>
                <option  ng-model="search" ng-repeat="city in data.city | orderBy:'name'">
                                  {{city.name}}</option>
            </optgroup>
  </select>
```

i know that the ng-model code should go in the html **select** tag like this:

```
<select  ng-model="search" data-placeholder="Search..."  etc..
```

but that doesn't filter the results in the table, what happens is that the table goes blank, i have no idea why, unless i quit the filter the data goes back to table. What i can do to make the code work as intended?

**EDIT**: i have been watching what are the values in ng-model="search", so far they are treated like an array like this: **["data1","data2"...]** (since i added the **value={{localidad.nombre}}** on the options tag), if i access to certain value in the array like this {{search[0]}}, displays the text normally like this **data1**, but still not filtering the table results, the table goes blank, any ideas on what's going on?

**EDIT 2**:i stumbled on some questions on stack overflow 
[How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs/21169596#21169596), this could be an issue? i mean the filters are supposed to be multiple.

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me if this in a different Tangent to what your after but I wrote a quick example. Which I think  covers what your trying to go after.[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqhh1jw2/) Driven of the Value you have assigned to the option tag.

```
            <p><select data-ng-model="search"  >
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NV">New Vegas</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            </select>
            </p>

            <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in someFile| filter:search | orderBy:'name'" style="border: 1px solid black;" >
            <td>{{data.number}}</td>
             <td>{{data.state + ', ' + data.city}}</td>
             <td> more data goes here etc...</td>
            </tr>
            <table>
```

Comment: This gets closer to the solution, but as i mentioned before when i print the value of the **ng-model** display now like this **["someCity1","someCity2"]**, at least it's much better than this **["\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t someCity1","\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t someCity2"]**

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is *what* within your search model you want it to go by. `search` itself is an object of key values.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in someFile | filter:search.XXXX | orderBy:'name'">
```

Where XXXX is the property name of what you're trying to search by. Whether it be `search.Guid` / `search.Name` whatever you have there.

Comment: Yes, this kinda works when i print the ng-model values on the webpage i get something like this **["\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t someCity1","\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t someCity2"]**, so in way it's working, but for some reason when i try to put in the filter the name of the property, it doesn't print nothing and doesn't filter the table either.