# AngularJS : custom filter with special rules

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to make multi filter, that filters three properties in object.

what I already did:

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="selectedCard in Cards | filter {
    status:filterValueStatus,
    monitorLevel:filterValueType,
    monitorSystem:filterValue
} ">
```

The problem is that I need to show the object if status equals to '2' , and not continue to the two filtered properties : monitorLevel and monitorSystem that come after. (It doesn't work). 
Also I need to show the object if status equals to '3' , then filter it by the two properties monitorLevel and monitorSystem.

In summary it needs to check the status and only after , to decide whether to make the other two filters or not.

The filter I built until now :

```
app.filter('cardFilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(status, monitorLevel,monitorSystem) {
        if (status == '2') {
            return $filter('filter')(status);
        } else {
        return $filter('filter')(status,monitorLevel,monitorSystem);
        }
    };
}]);
```

**the answer :**

```
  <div class="" ng-repeat="selectedCard in Cards | filter: filterValueStatus == '2' ? {status:'2'} : {status:'3', monitorLevel:filterValueLevel, monitorSystem:filterValue}">
```

Comment: You could do it in one filter more than likely. What have you tried?

Comment: I didn't try any thing, i don't know how to split this filter

Comment: There is no need to split it I don't think, you could just make one filter with a few if statements inside?

Comment: I have never built a costume filter' do you have an example ?

Comment: maybe you can import the two other filters in the first filters, using dependency injection, and use $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator) : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter ...which is a way to trigger filters in controllers/directives/services... and other filters.

Comment: If you never built your own filter, what are the filters in your code ? Where do they come from ?

Comment: each one of them is a variable, the filter only shows what eq to the variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs/21169596#21169596 . That is a little complex, I just googled around a bit, but the general idea is you can make a custom filter as complex (or not) as you need. Give it a shot, and if you get stuck, try posting the filter code here.

Comment: app.filter('cardFilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
        return function(status, monitorLevel,monitorSystem) {
            if (status == '1') return;
            if (status == '2') {
                return $filter('filter')(status);
            } 
            return $filter('filter')(status,monitorLevel,monitorSystem);
        };
    }]);

Comment: like what i did above ??

Answer (score 0):

You can  split your filters into 2 and use ternary operation. You get the concept:

```
<div ng-repeat="selectedCard in Cards | filter : { status:filterValueStatus} |
   filter : selectedCard.status === 2 ? {} : {
        monitorLevel:filterValueType,
        monitorSystem:filterValue
   } 
} ">
```

Comment: what does this mean : filter : selectedCard.status === 2 ? {} :

Comment: selectedCard.status === 2 ? {} : {
        monitorLevel:filterValueType,
        monitorSystem:filterValue
   }.  This is a ternary operation. If status is equal to 2 the your result will be  filtered by an empty object(which does no filtering). Otherwise it will filter the result by monitorLevel and monitor System

Comment: this part doesn't work: filter : selectedCard.status == '2' ? {} : {monitorLevel:filterValueType,monitorSystem:filterValue}

Comment: I am sorry. I think I am wrong. You will still have to create a customized filter for your purpose

Comment: I change it , and now it works , it suppose to be like this :

Comment: <div class="" ng-repeat="selectedCard in Cards | filter: status == '2' ? filter:{status:filterValueStatus} : {status:filterValueStatus,monitorLevel:filterValueType,monitorSystem:filterValue}">

Answer (score 0):

the answer is not so complex as I thought it would be as start.

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="selectedCard in Cards | filter: filterValueStatus == '2' ? {status:'2'} : {status:'3', monitorLevel:filterValueLevel, monitorSystem:filterValue}">
```

It first , check if status equals to '2' and only afterwords filters the cards, according to the status.