# multiple values for filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter

So I want to check for multiple values in array of objects with $filter from angular. You can find my code below.

```
angular.module('app', [])

function ParentCtrl($scope, $filter){
    var list = [{name : "test", value : "test"}, {name: "test1", value: "test"}, { name: 'test', value: 'test1'}];
    var newTemp = $filter("filter")(lst, {name:'test'});
    console.log(newTemp);
}
```

So what I want is in newTemp to have all objects that have name=test or value=test. With code above I am getting all objects that have name=test. So how can i add one more condition??

I tried also with

```
var newTemp = $filter("filter")(lst, {name:'test'}) || $filter("filter")(lst, {value:'test'});
```

but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

[How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs/21169596#21169596)

There's a couple different ways you can create a custom filter.

Comment: Well i look at that before I write this question. But i try with some solutions and no success..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    var list = [{name : "test", value : "test"}, {name: "test1", value: "test"}, {     name: 'test', value: 'test1'}];
    var newTemp = $filter('filter')(list, function(value, index, array){
        return value.name == "test"; //or any other condition
    });
    console.log(newTemp);
```