# Filtering only specific fields in objects by following OR operator with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, filtering

I have a list of items. Example of one item:

```
{"id":7,"name":"ItemName","status":"Active","statusFrom":"2016-01-04T00:00:00","development":"Started","devStartedFrom":"2016-01-04T00:00:00","owner":"Owner"}
```

I would like the filter to look only in *name*, *status* and *owner* and return either (OR operator) objects. When filter is defined like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {name:myFilterquery, status:myFilterquery, owner:myFilterquery}">
```

The filter returns objects by following AND operator.

How would you define a filter to query only by specific fields of an object, but following the OR operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picked up the [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filte) library and defined the solution this way:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filterBy : ['name', 'status', 'owner'] : filterQuery">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do your own filtering where you get to chose OR over AND:

```
[
    {id: 123, name: 'abc'},
    {id: 456, name: 'xyz'},
    {id: 999, name: 'qwe'},
].filter(item => item.id === 123 || item.name === 'xyz') // [{id: 123, name: 'abc'}, {id: 456, name: 'xyz'}]
```

Update: Ah, you meant in the mark-up!

Answered here?: [How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs)