# $filter with OR

Tags: angularjs, firebase

For a single condition my filter is ok :

```
 var myArray = $filter('filter')(data,{ myPropertyName1: 4 } );
```

But I want to filter by "or" condition trying this syntax :

```
 var myArray = $filter('filter')(data, { myPropertyName1: 4 }  || { myPropertyName2: 4} );
```

No errors but incorrect results.

What is wrong ?

Comment: You can't have such kind of filter, I'd suggest you to create custom filter..

Comment: @GCoe, check out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: Thank you Pankaj and Jon