# Angular filter on two objects of an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a filter on the JS side of angular.

```
$filter('filter')($scope.ArrayofUserObjects, {Active: true, ID: passedInValue});
```

***NOTE*** - my array is is an array of objects

Let's say my array has 50 active users and 10 inactive users.

The `passedInValue` is an inactive user's ID. This filter at present will return `0` because each parameter of the array in essence is `&&` together.

**Question ---**

I would like to alter this filter so the objects are `||` together, which means the resulting filter would return `51`

Is this possible?

Comment: Filters are functions so they should be able to return whatever you want but I have trouble understanding what you mean to ask.

Comment: Do you to add $scope.array and the second object passed as arguments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own filter:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.ArrayofUserObjects, function(value){return value.Active || value.ID == passedInValue});
```

Comment: I needed to use this in more than one place, so I broke it out into a function by itself. Thanks for the help.