# How to filter a select list in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I see a couple of other questions like this, but their answers aren't working for me.

I have the code below which is displaying data in a table using AngularJS.  I want to filter the query to only display the SecurityID numbers of 8, 9, and 10.  When I add the filter as shown below I get nothing.  When I remove the filter all of the securities appear.  What is the easiest way to write this filter?

```html
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="SecuritiesCtrl">
            Select A Forex Pair:
            <select ng-model="SecuritiesModel" ng-options="x.SecurityID as x.TrueSymbol for x in Securities | filter:{ SecurityID: 8,9,10 }" ng-change="GetQuotes();" ng-bind="date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"></select><br />

         <table id="QuotesTable" class="MyTable" style="display:none;">
              <tr>
                <th class="MyTable">Time</th>
                <th class="MyTable">Open</th>
                <th class="MyTable">Hi</th>
                <th class="MyTable">Lo</th>
                <th class="MyTable">Close</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="x in Quotes">
                <td class="MyTable">{{ x.QuoteTime }}</td>
                <td class="MyTable">{{ x.Open }}</td>
                <td class="MyTable">{{ x.Hi }}</td>
                <td class="MyTable">{{ x.Lo }}</td>
                <td class="MyTable">{{ x.Close }}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: u should use custom filter for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a filter on several values, I recommend you to create a controller function to filter.

```
$scope.interestingSecurityIds = [8, 9, 10];

$scope.filterBySecurityId = function(security) {
    return ($scope.interestingSecurityIds.indexOf(security.SecurityID) !== -1);
};
```

With this filter in your view :

```
<select ng-model="SecuritiesModel" ng-options="x.SecurityID as x.TrueSymbol for x in Securities | filter: filterBySecurityId" ng-change="GetQuotes();" ng-bind="date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"></select>
```

JSFiddle mockup [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2a6wr5Lk/).

You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869686/1517335).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can't get this to work either.  I don't know why.  I tried putting a breakpoint in the filterBySecurityId function, but it never hits in Developer Tools.

Comment: @SteveGaines There is no error in the console logs ?

Comment: I think he missed calling function name. Use like this  **filter: filterBySecurityId()**

Comment: @bivale - It looks like there is an error in console logs.  I'm pretty new to using Developer Tools.  Here's what it says (in part): Error: options is undefined
writeNgOptionsValue@http://www.stevegaines.us/Scripts/angular.js:27783:15

Comment: @ArunShinde Nope you should not use paranthesis : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: @bivale - I see another error relating to the filter: "Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {}
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%7D
minErr/<@http://www.stevegaines.us/Scripts/angular.js:68:12

Comment: @Steves: Thanks. I missed that part.

Comment: @bivale -  I found this page that explains how to solve this error, but I'm not strong enough in AngluarJS to understand it yet: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray

Comment: I made a light mockup of your application in this JSFiddle so you can try the filter without bugs : https://jsfiddle.net/2a6wr5Lk/

Comment: @bivale - Thanks for all the effort.  It still doesn't work for me because my data is not an array, so the log still shows the filter/notarray error.  That seems like a pretty limiting design in AngularJS.  I give up.  I've decided that the page can display the data unfiltered.  If you see a quick fix for this array issue, I'll make it.  Otherwise, I'll continue onto something else..