# Angular filter with list of items in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an array of objects with user and interests. I would like to `filter` the list based on interests. An user can have multiple interests and when selected interests check boxes the list should filter out based on those interests. I've used a basic filter on ng-repeat but it's not working.

If I select "sports" then "John" and "Rosaline" should be shown.
If I select "movies" and "reading" then all 3 users should be shown.
Below is my code.

> Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/A0ojO3MH8rDhFJVXlEAs?p=preview

**View:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" style="padding:20px">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.reading" ng-true-value="'reading'" ng-false-value="''">reading
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.sports" ng-true-value="'sports'" ng-false-value="''">sports
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.movies" ng-true-value="'movies'" ng-false-value="''">movies
<br><br>
Selected Values: {{selectedValues}}
<hr>
    <div ng-repeat="d in data | filter: selectedValues">
      <h4>
      Name: {{d.user}}
      </h4>

        <h4>
      Interests: {{d.interests}}
      </h4>

      <hr>

</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.selection = {};
    $scope.data = [
        {
            user: "John",
            interests: ["reading","sports","movies"]
        },
           {
            user: "David",
            interests: ["movies","reading"]
        },
        {
            user: "Rosaline",
            interests: ["sports","movies"]
        }
    ];
    $scope.$watchCollection('selection', function () {
                $scope.selectedValues = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.selection, function (value, key) {
                    if (value) {
                        $scope.selectedValues.push(value);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs/21169596#21169596

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here is**](https://plnkr.co/edit/03ZItE13XsdZurg4yJqV?p=preview) one of many ways to filter objects in such examples.

I suggest getting rid of using `$watch` in this situation and implement checkboxes functionality via simple `ngChange` directive. Example below.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.reading" ng-change="selectInterest('reading')">reading
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.sports" ng-change="selectInterest('sports')">sports
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.movies" ng-change="selectInterest('movies')">movies

$scope.selectInterest = function(interest){
  $scope.selection[interest] = !!$scope.selection[interest];
};
```

For filtering data I recommend using [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) or (just to simplify example) implement this filter like a controller function.

```
$scope.filterUsers = function(user){
  return Object.keys($scope.selection).some(function (item) {
    return user.interests.indexOf(item) >= 0 && $scope.selection[item];
  });
};
```

You can look at and play with the whole code of my example at the link above.

Comment: Thank you @Artyom Pranovich..what if I want to show the data, without checking the check boxes, by default and hide the items based on selection.

Comment: @SateeshKumarAlli, am I right that you'd like the implementation like that https://plnkr.co/edit/5OUyv6XT3vTdan7Amqkg?p=preview? It displays all data the first time when you load the page and then filter the data based on checkbox selections.

Comment: exactly. Thank you. It would be nice if the data is shown when check boxes are un-checked.

Comment: @SateeshKumarAlli, here is what did you ask for https://plnkr.co/edit/EnbY8w2fg6uBPQFGUuyk?p=preview

Comment: This helps me. Thank you very much. @ArtyomPranovich

Answer (score 1):

Modify your html a bit in ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data" ng-hide="selectedValues.length > 0 && !filteredData(d.interests)">
  <h4>
    Name: {{d.user}}
  </h4>

  <h4>
     Interests: {{d.interests}}
 </h4>

  <hr>

</div>
```

And add this function in script.js

```
             $scope.filteredData = function (data) {
             var found = false;
                 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedValues.length; i++) {
                    if (data.indexOf($scope.selectedValues[i]) !== -1) { found = true; break; }
                 }   
              return found;
         };
```

Live example : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/y8tqNiIU6p3x8d9zcdzL?p=preview

This will work ! Thanks

Comment: Thank you @KrishCdbry. This example filters interests but I would like to filter users based on interests.

Comment: Yes done ! I have edited the answer please have a look at it. It will work

Comment: Your code is working fine but it's not giving desired output. Suppose if I select reading and sports it should show both John and Rosaline but it's showing only one person. I'll go with @Artyom Pranovich's solution

Comment: I though all selected interests should be there, But if any one of them then I updated. It is just a line change. you can visit the plunker now

Answer (score 0):

Your can keep your filters in some array e.g. `filterInterests` and then your HTML could looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
  <div  ng-show="hasInterest(d.interests, filterInterests)">
  // Your code here
  </div>
</div>
```

And your function will looks like:

```
function hasInterest(data, interests){
  var result = false;
  // Iterate over interests from filter and check them all in provided data
  for(var=i, i<interests.length, i++){
   if(data.indexOf(i) != -1) result = true       
   else result = false;
  }
  return result;
}
```