# How can I filter the values onclicking of radio button in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

How can i filter `category values` when clicking on a radio button?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/608O1UxffPB7dixErnKo?p=preview)

- Actually I want to filter category values.

**For Example :-** in plunker we have displayed category values using of `data-ng-bind`. there are two radio buttons are available, `1.Moral Ethics` `2. Religion & Culture`. if we click the first radio button of `moral ethics` it's should `filter` only the `moral ethis values` and if we click the second radio button of `religon & Culture` it's should `filter` only the `religon & Culture values`.  .

**My HTML radio button:-**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <label class="green"><input type="radio" name="myquestion" data-ng-model="myquestion.category" value="myquestion" ><span>Moral Ethics</span></label>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-3">
 <label class="green"><input type="radio" name="culture" data-ng-model="culture.category" value="culture" ><span>Religion & Culture</span></label>
 </div>
```

**My HTML Filter:-**

```
ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: myquestion | filter:culture"
```

**My Html Data:-**

```
 <div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:myquestion | filter:culture">
   <small>
   <span >{{$index + 1}}.</span>
   <span data-ng-bind="question.category"></span>
   </small>
</div>
```

**My Controller Data:-**

```
 $scope.questions = [  
   {  
 "_id":"5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
 "user":{  
 "roles":[  
 "admin"
 ],
         "profileImageURL":"./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },
  "friend_tag":[  

      ],
  "emotion":"Confused",
  "category":"Religion & Culture",
  "created":"2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
   },
   {  
  "_id":"5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
  "user":{  
  "roles":[  
            "admin"
         ],
         "profileImageURL":"./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },
  "friend_tag":[  

      ],
  "emotion":"Confused",
  "category":"Moral Ethics",
  "created":"2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
   },
   {  
  "_id":"5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
  "user":{  
  "roles":[  
  "admin"
         ],
         "profileImageURL":"./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },
  "friend_tag":[  

      ],
  "emotion":"Confused",
  "category":"Environment & Health",
  "created":"2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
   },
   {  
  "_id":"5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
  "user":{  
  "roles":[  
  "admin"
         ],
         "profileImageURL":"./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },
  "friend_tag":[  

      ],
  "emotion":"Confused",
  "category":"Environment & Health",
  "created":"2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
   },
   {  
  "_id":"5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
  "user":{  
  "roles":[  
  "admin"
         ],
         "profileImageURL":"./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },
      "friend_tag":[  

      ],
      "emotion":"Confused",
      "category":"Religion & Culture",
      "created":"2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
   },
   {  
      "_id":"5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user":{  
         "roles":[  
            "admin"
         ],
         "profileImageURL":"./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },
      "friend_tag":[  

      ],
      "emotion":"Confused",
      "category":"Religion & Culture",
      "created":"2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
   },
   {  
      "_id":"5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user":{  
         "roles":[  
            "admin"
         ],
         "profileImageURL":"./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },
      "friend_tag":[  

      ],
      "emotion":"Confused",
      "category":"Moral Ethics",
      "created":"2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
   }
]
```

- please look my plunker for reference and help me.. please update the plunker as well to know the exact solution...thanks.

Comment: It is very simple assign common view model to radio buttons, and assign that value to filter. Take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/zzAwBXysnoFCZQyqKqF0?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change value of check box  like below that's it

```
<input type="radio" name="myquestion" data-ng-model="myquestion.category" value="Moral Ethics" >                       
<input type="radio" name="myquestion" data-ng-model="myquestion.category" value="Religion & Culture" >
```

and your repeated div as below

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:myquestion">
      <small>
                    <span >{{$index + 1}}.</span>
                      <span data-ng-bind="question.category"></span>
                  </small>

    </div>
```

as well as please find updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Zzc6nRylgETOvQp3SI2?p=preview)

Comment: completely my pleasure :) i hope it'll help you

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in using radio buttons in angular so here is some changes you have to do. Below is the updated code for your view.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="green">
        <input type="radio" name="myquestion" data-ng-model="selectedCategory" value="Moral Ethics"><span>Moral Ethics</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="green">
        <input type="radio" name="culture" data-ng-model="selectedCategory" value="Religion & Culture"><span>Religion & Culture</span></label>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:selectedCategory">
      <small>
                    <span >{{$index + 1}}.</span>
                      <span data-ng-bind="question.category"></span>
                  </small>

    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment...will check and update you

Answer (score 1):

I update your Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/uN2NoO8JaBUINRkvEljt?p=preview

for that:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
 <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="green"><input type="radio" name="myquestion" data-ng-model="category" value="Moral Ethics" ><span>Moral Ethics</span></label></div>

<div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="green"><input type="radio" name="culture" data-ng-model="category" value="Religion & Culture" ><span>Religion & Culture</span>      </label></div>

 <div ng-repeat="question in questions|filter:category ">
    <small>
                <span >{{$index + 1}}.</span>
                  <span data-ng-bind="question.category"></span>
              </small>

    </div>

  </div>
```

it works fine.