# angularJs filter on single column with different value based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-filters

I have one json dataset in angular say

```
$scope.data = [{
      call_id: '1',
      title: 'test',
      start: new Date(elem.call_date),
      backgroundColor: "#9f1eab",
      borderColor: "#9f1eab",
      filterByCheckbox: 'filterOne'},
    {
      call_id: '1',
      title: 'test',
      start: new Date(elem.call_date),
      backgroundColor: "#9f1eab",
      borderColor: "#9f1eab",
      filterByCheckbox: 'filterTwo'
    }];
```

Now I have 3 checkox

```
 filterOne
 filterTwo
 filterThree
```

Now I want to filter `$scope.data` based on above 3 checkbox selection.
Column to filter in `$scope.data` is `filterByCheckbox`

So above is my data set which contains list of records having column `filterByCheckbox` I want to filter data based on that column.

If first 2 checkbox checked,`$scope.data` should be filtered on column `filterByCheckbox` containing `filterOne` and `filterTwo` value.

How can i achieve this in angularjs?

I have tried:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.data, { filterByCheckbox: 'filterTwo' })
```

But it works for only one checkbox.

Comment: you need to share your code for `$scope.data` and what you have done so far

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs)

Comment: can this be achieved without using any loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.filterdData=[];   
angular.forEach($scope.data,function (val,key){
    if(($scope.filterOne && val.filterByCheckbox==='filterOne')||($scope.filterTwo && val.filterByCheckbox==='filterTwo')||($scope.filterThree && val.filterByCheckbox==='filterThree')){
    $scope.filterdData.push(val);
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it using [`ngTrueValue` and `ngFalseValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D). They are basically the value to which the expression should be set when checked and unchecked respectively.

So, your checkboxes would look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='search.filterOne' 
       data-ng-true-value="'filterOne'" data-ng-false-value='' />filterOne
```

Now, all we need to do is use those as filter. Like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | filter: search.filterOne | filter: search.filterTwo">
  <pre>{{item.filterByCheckbox}}</pre>
  ...
</div>
```

Find working example below!

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.search = []

  $scope.data = [{
    call_id: '1',
    title: 'test',
    start: new Date(),
    backgroundColor: "#9f1eab",
    borderColor: "#9f1eab",
    filterByCheckbox: 'filterOne'
  }, {
    call_id: '1',
    title: 'test',
    start: new Date(),
    backgroundColor: "#9f1eab",
    borderColor: "#9f1eab",
    filterByCheckbox: 'filterTwo'
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='search.filterOne' data-ng-true-value="'filterOne'" data-ng-false-value='' />filterOne
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.filterTwo" data-ng-true-value="'filterTwo'" data-ng-false-value=''/>filterTwo
  <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter: search.filterOne | filter: search.filterTwo">
    <pre>{{item.filterByCheckbox}}</pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```