# Angular filter with OR operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, operator-keyword

I'm trying to build a filter from a range slider.

Is it possible to set when my range slider be on one of the positions to show more than one category?

With the code below I can filter using the range, but he puts on the filter only the first word and nothing more after the OR operator. Anyone can help me?

```
$scope.filterRange = filterRange;

function filterRange() {
    if (this.rangemodel == 1) {
        $scope.categoryfilter = 'web' || 'ecommerce '; // something like that!
    } else if(this.rangemodel == 2) {
        $scope.categoryfilter = 'branding' || 'video'; // something like that!
    } ;
};

<div ng-repeat="project in projects | filter: {category: categoryfilter}">
```

I've already see the other post here, but still not getting how i can make this happen. =(

Thanks to Daniel, here's the working solution:

```
$scope.projetos = [];

$scope.filtroRange = filtroRange; 

function filtroRange() {
    if (this.rangemodel == 1) {
        $scope.categoryFilter = function(projeto) {
        if (projeto.categoria === 'site institucional' || projeto.categoria === 'ecommerce') {
            console.log('filtrando');
            return projeto;      
            }
        };
    } else if (this.rangemodel == 2) {
        $scope.categoryFilter = function(projeto) {
        if (projeto.categoria === 'branding' || projeto.categoria === 'email marketing') {
            console.log('filtrando');
            return projeto;      
            }
        };
    }
 };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom filter function like so:

```
$scope.categoryFilter = function(project) {
    if (this.rangemodel == 1) {
        if (project.category === 'web' || project.category === 'ecommerce') {
            return project;      
        }
    } else if (this.rangemodel == 2) {
        if (project.category === 'branding' || project.category === 'video') {
                return project;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then your html would simply call this function as the filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects | filter: categoryFilter">
```