# AngularJS filter field according to values of an array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-filter

I have an Array and this array contains some Id's.
I would like to filter my result according to Id's.

For Example please see the below code snippet. 
How can I show the records which 'StatusId' located in the 'ids' array?
According to my example, I want to list only:

AAA
BBB
CCC

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.ids = [{
            "id": 1
        }, {
            "id": 2
        }, {
            "id": 3
        }]

        $scope.records = [
            {
                "Name": "AAA",
                "StatusId": 1
            },
            {
                "Name": "BBB",
                "StatusId": 1
            },
            {
                "Name": "CCC",
                "StatusId": 2
            },
            {
                "Name": "DDD",
                "StatusId": 4
            },
            {
                "Name": "EEE",
                "StatusId": 4
            },
]


    });
</script>


<body>
    <div id="idctrl" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in records">
                {{ x.Name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should create a custom filter. Have a look at this answer. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869436/5358917](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869436/5358917)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript 'filter' function:

```
records = $scope.records.filter((record) => {
    return record.StatusId === 1
});
```

This will return a new array that only contains records with a StatusId of 1. You can these use this updated array to display your desired records.

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear. I've added your function into my code but the result hasn't changed.

Comment: @Grcn Arrays have a filter function that takes a _function_ as input which should return true or false. It passes each element of the array through that function provided, and returns a _new_ array of the elements that returned true. [Read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Just an FYI, if you're working with arrow functions, and the function _just_ returns a value, you can write it like this: `(record)=>record.StatusId === 1` (or as `record=>record.StatusId === 1`, since there's exactly one parameter)

Comment: Thank you guys. I understand the point and have solved my problem.