# Filter through array of objects

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects (~650) in the format

```
[1: {firstName: "Hello",
 lastName: "World",
 shortName: "h.world",
...some other items
},
2: {firstName: "John",
 lastName: "Doe",
 shortName: "j.doe",
...some other items
}]
```

And I need to filter through the list based on a text input, which should search `firstName+ " "+lastName`. So searching `He` or `Hello W` will return `Hello World`, and searching `Hellow` wouldn't return it (case doesn't matter). What's the best way to filter the array? I've seen Angulars filter method but I've not yet worked out how to do it.

EDIT What I have

```
<div ng-controller="NotesCtrl">
    <p>Search for a user to see there sessions and notes</p>
    <input type="text" id="user" ng-model="search.firstName" />

    {literal}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="u in users | filter:search">{{u.activeDirectoryName}}</li>
    </ul>
    {/literal}
</div>
```

From what I've read that should work, but the list doesn't filter. Do I need to do anything in the controller to get this to work?

Answer: Turns out even though in PHP my data was an array, in Javascript it was an object, changed it around a bit so it came through as an array and it seems to be working now.

Comment: You might try looking at the docs. It's pretty straight forward http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: I've tried what the docs say but the list doesn't fitler (See my edit)

Comment: Check out my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs/20272713#20272713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `search` should be a function in your controller that takes each item in the array and returns `true` or `false` depending if it passes the filter or not.