# How to exclude some fields from filtering using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My json:

```
name : 'name1'
age : '16'
error : 'some text etc'
address : 'adress details '
etc
```

My filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="datalist in datalists | filter:searchquery">
name : {{ name}} etc
</div>
<input type="text"  value="Search" ng-model="searchquery">
```

Here I don't want to filter error details, error may be a list of objects sometimes.
How can I exclude error field?

I've tried:

```
<div ng-repeat="datalist in datalists | filter:searchquery && !error">
```

but that's not working.

Please give me suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: Write a custom filter that ignores that property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13216282/189756

Answer (score 3):

```
angular.module('dataListFilters', []).filter('excludeErrors', function() {
  return function( data ) {
    if (!data.error ) {
       return data;
    }
  };
});
```

Then you must include it in your app:

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ngRoute','controller','excludeErrors']);

<div ng-repeat="datalist in datalists | filter: excludeErrors | filter: searchquery ">
```