# How to use orderBy and filter with ng-repeat, using an object (instead of array)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have data "like" this:

```
$scope.persons = {
        "ID123": {
            name_de: "Andre",
            name_en: "Anrew",
            age: 30,
            description: "He is the father of xyz and . . .",

             . . .

        },
        "IDabc": {
            name_de: "Markus",
            name_en: "Mark",
            age: 20,

             . . .
        },
        "IDxyz": {
            name_de: "Isaak",
            name_en: "Isaac",
            age: 23,

             . . .
        }

    . . .

}
```

and i have an input/ng-repeat:

```
<input ng-model="query" placeholder="Suche . . .">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="p in persons | orderBy:'name_de' | filter:query"> Some output here . . . </li>
</ul>
```

Now is the question how can i order and filter this?

It **worked with an Array of persons**, but i need the "ID's" so the object is necessary!?

I am looking also for a way to filter the object by N-properties
 e.g for name_de AND name_en (so it will show ID123 if i search for Andre and also if i search for Andrew) BUT ignoring the text of "description" (first i had the problem that the filter checks ALL properties)

Comment: Both `orderBy` and `filter` filters don't support the Object source out of the box. You either have to write a custom filter or covert it into Array (store each ID as another property) before pass it to filters.

Comment: Try: filter: { name_de: query, name_en: query }

Comment: this does not work Rob :( ty anyways  If i convert it to an array how can i adress id's? e.g  i link to other persons (father, mother and other relations) with persons.idxyz(.xyz)

Comment: Then please include more code of what you have tried e.g. how the relationships are stored and query.

Comment: until now the data isn't complete and i just startet. One thing i want to use is e.g. to check if the father has also a father property = then it's the grandfather (an i don't have to add grandfather as a property by myself) my ID's consist of the first 4 Letters+ length of the name  + 0/1 (male/female) + A/B/C . .. if the ID would not be unique (this is useful if i want to use data from 1 person, because i know the name and anything else (just in rare cases i have to check which one i want A/B/C... ) i could do this with persons[index] of course but this wouldn't be very "clear"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use toArrayfilter module more info please see here :http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter

and there sample demo for your solution http://jsbin.com/nimoxa/1/edit
JS:

```
angular.module('angular-toArrayFilter', [])

.filter('toArray', function () {
  return function (obj, addKey) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Object)) {
      return obj;
    }

    if ( addKey === false ) {
      return Object.values(obj);
    } else {
      return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
        return Object.defineProperty(obj[key], '$key', { enumerable: false, value: key});
      });
    }
  };
});

var app = angular.module('app', ['angular-toArrayFilter']);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.persons = {

    "IDabc": {
            name_de: "Markus",
            name_en: "Mark",
            age: 20,


        },
        "ID123": {
            name_de: "Andre",
            name_en: "Anrew",
            age: 30,
            description: "He is the father of xyz and . . .",



        },

        "IDxyz": {
            name_de: "Isaak",
            name_en: "Isaac",
            age: 23,


        }   

};

});
```

html:

```
body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
<input ng-model="query" placeholder="Suche . . .">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="p in persons | toArray | orderBy:'age' | filter:query"> {{p.name_de}} -> {{p.name_en}} </li>
</ul>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: that looks great :) i will take a look but one last thing... if i search for "father" it stil shows Andrew .. because the filter checks all properties. How can i "ingnore" some properties?

Comment: @easyX ie: if you want search only for name_de use : `filter:{'name_de':query}`

Comment: and if i want to search for name_de AND name_en? (or any other combination)?

Comment: @easyX please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question on

> It worked with an Array of persons, but i need the "ID's" so the
>   object is necessary!?

can you include ID as a property of your person objects so that they will look like this?

```
$scope.persons = [
    { id: "ID123",
      name_de: "Andre",
      name_en: "Anrew",
      age: 30,
      description: "He is the father of xyz and . . .",
      . . .
    },
    { id: "IDabc",
      name_de: "Markus",
      name_en: "Mark",
      age: 20,
    },
         . . .
];
```

To search by name_de AND name_en (or any other properties for the matter), you can try writing your custom filter. It's fairly easy.

```
var app = angular.module("YourApp");
app.filter('MyCustomFilter', function(){
    return function(objects, criteria){
        if(!criteria)            
            return objects;

        var filterResult = new Array();
        for(var index in objects)
            if(objects[index].name_de.indexOf(criteria) != -1 || objects[index].name_en.indexOf(criteria) != -1)
                filterResult.push(objects[index]);
        return filterResult;
    }
});
```

Your HTML will look like this:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="personFilter" />
<div data-ng-repeat="person in persons | MyCustomFilter:personFilter"> ... </div>
```

Comment: i want to add properties like father:"id123" so i could do stuff like that: gradfather = persons[persons.IDabc.father].father i don't know how to do that with an array (without abstract index numbers) At the end i will have more then 1000 persons.. so i need a clear view

Comment: ok, in the case, what you did with the associative array is correct.