# searchKeyword not working in AngularJS filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angular-filters

I am writing an app using AngularJS on the front end. I want to search through a table by any word/field; one search box for everything. According to this article here: http://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/searchtable
I can use filter: searchKeyword to do just this.

This is my code, and it is not working as expected.

```
<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchKeyword"></label>

<table ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: sort | filter: searchKeyword">
    <tr>
       <td> {{index(post)}} </td>

       <td> {{post.title}} </td>

       <td> {{post.author}} </td>

       <td> {{post.content}} </td>

       <td> {{post.date | date: "d/M/yyyy"}} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What should I do? Thank you

Comment: Show us your controller, please.

Comment: Please refer to this new post with some modifications. My controller code is in there @isherwood thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394920/angularjs-filter-search-not-working-at-all

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Controller**

```
    $scope.posts = [
      {title:'Title one', author:'Author one', content: 'Content one'},
      {title:'Title two', author:'Author two', content: 'Content two'},
      {title:'Title three', author:'Author three', content: 'Content three'}
    ];

    $scope.searchKeyword = '';
    $scope.sort = 'title';
```

**View**

```
<label>Search:
  <input ng-model="searchKeyword">
</label>

<table ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: sort | filter: searchKeyword">
  <tr>
    <td> {{post.title}} </td>
    <td> {{post.author}} </td>
    <td> {{post.content}} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This does not work for me, when I search something nothing changes @Sofre Garevski

Comment: This solution doesn't work 100% for me. I don't know why. Sometimes the search works, it pulls results as expected. Sometimes it does not. For example, when my post.title is B, the search can find it. When it is A or C or D, it doesn't find them. Could it be the post.date interfering with it somehow? Btw I am using MongoDB to store the results

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue myself.

I did something like this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="searchFilter.itemDesc" 
    placeholder="Search...." />

<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchFilter">
```

each item has a property of itemDesc

the downside to this approach is that it only lets you search one property of the object being repeated

If you are wanting it to be searched by the different properties of the object

you can do something similar to

[Filtering by Multiple Specific Model Properties in AngularJS (in OR relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship)

Comment: I did follow the example you provided, and it isn't working for me. Please take a look at my new post with updates @Teliren http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394920/angularjs-filter-search-not-working-at-all

Comment: Update: this approach works fine for a single field. I am really curious to why this is happening. @Teliren