# AngularJS filter search not working at all

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am writing an app using AngularJS on the front end. I want to search through a table by any word/field; one search box for everything. I tried to follow this plunker's working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/aIuSDYlFbC4doW6pfsC9?p=preview

This is my code on the front end:

```
<div class = "row">
   <label>Search: <input ng-model="query"></label>
</div>

<div class = "row">
  <table ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: sort | filter: search">
    <tr>
       <td> {{index(post)}} </td>

       <td> {{post.title}} </td>

       <td> {{post.author}} </td>

       <td> {{post.content}} </td>

       <td> {{post.date | date: "d/M/yyyy"}} </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And this is inside my main controller:

```
'use strict';
 $scope.posts = posts.posts;

 $scope.search = function (row) {
    return (angular.lowercase(row.author).indexOf($scope.query || '') !== -1 ||
    angular.lowercase(row.title).indexOf($scope.query || '') !== -1 ||
    angular.lowercase(row.content).indexOf($scope.query || '') !== -1 ||
    angular.lowercase(row.date).indexOf($scope.query || '') !== -1 ||
 };
```

What should I do? Thank you

Comment: `filter: query`. I'd also pipe the array through `filter` before `orderBy`

Comment: the example you posted appears to be using angular 1.0.3; I doubt that any new projects are using this release.  Filters have changed drastically in angular, and this doesn't look like a function I would expect to work in modern angular releases.

Comment: also, you seem to have some syntax errors in that filter code, i.e. missing closing `)`, and a trailing `||` with no option after it.

Comment: @Phil: I know for a fact that the order on orderBy vs filter does not matter, and it will work the way it is now.

Comment: @VSO it might not make a functional difference but giving `orderBy` fewer items to sort will make it faster

Comment: @Phil: Makes sense, I didn't even consider that tbh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [searchKeyword not working in AngularJS filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393712/searchkeyword-not-working-in-angularjs-filter)

Answer (score 4):

Make a filter variable in your scope like so:

```
$scope.myFilter = "defaultFilterValue";
```

Bind your filter to a search field like this:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="myFilter"></input>
```

Put the filter in your html like so:

```
  <table ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: sort | filter: myFilter">
    <tr>
       <td> {{index(post)}} </td>

       <td> {{post.title}} </td>

       <td> {{post.author}} </td>

       <td> {{post.content}} </td>

       <td> {{post.date | date: "d/M/yyyy"}} </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

And then...oh wait, that's it. Let me know if you have any problems. [Tutorial here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular) on exactly your question.

---

Edit: This code is TESTED, so use it exactly as is and go from there. 
Html:

```
<div class = "row">
    <label>Search: <input type="text" ng-model="myFilter"></input></label>
</div>

<div class = "row">
    <table ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: sort | filter: myFilter">
        <tr>
            <td> {{index.post}} </td> //you had a weird formatting mistake here

            <td> {{post.title}} </td>

            <td> {{post.author}} </td>

            <td> {{post.content}} </td>

            <td> {{post.date | date: "d/M/yyyy"}} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.myFilter = "";

$scope.posts = [
        {index: 1, author: "Mark Twain", title: "Tom Sawyer", description: "And den Jim said some racist stuff", date:"02/05/1870"},
        {index: 2, author: "Eirch Remarque", title: "Western Front", description: "Our lost generation, bawww", date: "03/17/1955"}
];
```

Note: I REALLY recommend the tutorial I linked earlier. If you don't read it, then at least use table headers.

Comment: You don't need a default filter value if the default is *no filter*

Comment: So I took out all that stuff I had before in the controller and just put in $scope.myFilter = ""; and binded the filter to a search field and put the filter in the html. But it is not working? @VSO

Comment: Am I missing something else? @Phil

Comment: @VSO Thank you for this. I have read the tutorial and looked through the codes multiple times. This solution doesn't work 100% for me. I don't know why. Sometimes the search works, it pulls results as expected. Sometimes it does not. For example, when my post.title is B, the search can find it. When it is A or C or D, it doesn't find them. Could it be the post.date interfering with it somehow? Btw I am using MongoDB to store the results

Comment: Are you familiar with <pre>{{yourPostData | json}}></pre> tags convention to test your data from post? You can use it to see what data is returned. If some data is returned for every field, your ng-repeat should work. If your ng-repeat works, the filter should work. Basically, what I am saying is that I don't think the date is the issue as long as you are getting data. It's not like you are bringing BSON back to the client. P.S. I don't know what the problem is at the point, those are just suggestions. I can say with fair certainty that it has nothing to do with the date, as long as its there.

Comment: My ng-repeat returns the data just fine. What is really interesting is that when I do <label>Search: <input type="text" ng-model="myFilter.author"></input></label> or <label>Search: <input type="text" ng-model="myFilter.title"></input></label>, it works. So it is fine as long I am searching by a single field. However, I cannot do all fields at once. I have no idea why. @VSO

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class = "row">
   <label>Search: <input ng-model="query"></label>
</div>

<div class = "row">
    <table ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: sort | filter: query">
        <tr>
            <td> {{index(post)}} </td>
            <td> {{post.title}} </td>
            <td> {{post.author}} </td>
            <td> {{post.content}} </td>
            <td> {{post.date | date: "d/M/yyyy"}} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put an explanation saying what you changed and why it was wrong. That will help future visitors who may be having the same problem learn what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

**HTML:**

```
<label>Search:
  <input ng-model="searchKeyword" ng-model-options="{debounce:1000}">
</label>

<table ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: sort | filter: search">
  <tr>
    <td> {{post.title}} </td>
    <td> {{post.author}} </td>
    <td> {{post.content}} </td>
    <td> {{post.date}} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.posts = [{
  title: 'Title one ',
  author: 'Author one ',
  content: 'Content one ',
  date: new Date('10.10.2010')
}, {
  title: 'Title two ',
  author: 'Author two ',
  content: 'Content two ',
  date: new Date('11.11.2011')
}, {
  title: 'Title three ',
  author: 'Author three ',
  content: 'Content three ',
  date: new Date('12.12.2012')
}];

$scope.searchKeyword = '';
$scope.sort = 'title';

var authorMatch, titleMatch, contentMatch, dateMatch;

$scope.search = function(row) {
  authorMatch = row.author.toLowerCase().includes($scope.searchKeyword);
  titleMatch = row.title.toLowerCase().includes($scope.searchKeyword);
  contentMatch = row.content.toLowerCase().includes($scope.searchKeyword);
  dateMatch = row.date.toString().toLowerCase().includes($scope.searchKeyword);

  return authorMatch || titleMatch || contentMatch || dateMatch;
};
```

The debounce option is explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions). Includes function is new in JavaScript and is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring).

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to have Angular Strap for this approach? Because I am getting the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" error. @Sofre Garevski

Comment: Also this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined" @Sofre Garevski

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" - means that author or title or content or date is not defined. From here comes the second error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined". Make sure your data is consistent, or improve the method so it will check first if data exists.

Comment: I don't understand why they could be undefined. Because I double checked all the data names. @Sofre Garevski

Comment: But I definitely see why this would work @Sofre Garevski