# Filtering not working in angular js template

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter result based on multiple fields.

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in phones | filter: search | orderBy:orderProp" >
    <span>{{x.name}}</span>
    <p> {{ x.id}} </p>
    <p> {{ x.age}} </p>
  </li>

</ul>
```

In my controller I mentioned,

```
$scope.search = function (item) {

          return ( (item.name.indexOf($scope.query || '') ) !== -1 || (item.id.indexOf($scope.query || '')) !== -1);

    };
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/a1khZS9RcFdgitTYPgqs?p=preview

why does the filter not working ?
PS: I got error "TypeError: href is null" in firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error in your search function.

> item.id.indexOf is not a function

You're getting this because `item.id` is an integer literal.

You can try converting id.toString() first, or parse the query as an integer.

```
$scope.search = function(item) {

  return ((item.name.indexOf($scope.query || '')) !== -1 || (item.id.toString().indexOf($scope.query || '')) !== -1);

};
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuuH0JZK1Sd2LcXeMfs1?p=preview) is a working example.  The matching is case sensitive, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

just replace :

```
<li ng-repeat="x in phones | filter: search| orderBy:orderProp" >
```

with

```
<li ng-repeat="x in phones | filter: query | orderBy:orderProp" >
```

(the name of your scope attribute is `query` instead of `search`).

Comment: of course it's going to be work. But I want to filter by multiple fields. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship

Comment: I believe he is wanting to provide a filter function.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood what you needed. Michael G has a proper solution in his answer

Answer (score 0):

Change code of list.html like this. You have to pass textbox's ng-model with filter

```
<div class="container">

    <input type="text" ng-model="query">

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in phones | filter: query | orderBy:orderProp" >
        <span><a ng-href="#/phones/{{x.id}}">{{x.name}}</a></span>
        <p> {{ x.id}} </p>
        <p> {{ x.age}} </p>
      </li>

    </ul>

 </div>
```

Comment: I want to achieve this through filter function. pls see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship