# Filter an ng-repeat by multiple criteria with one being strict

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I have a search view and am trying to filter it by multiple criteria. The first is to filter by EmployeeName, SupervisorEmployeeName, and DepartmentName as one group, then filter by a status dropdown with two values: Active and Inactive. For the status dropdown, I would like to use strict filtering because even if I select "Active", it will return Inactive because the Inactive contains "active"

```
<select data-ng-model="employeeFilter.EmployeeStatusName" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="Active">Active</option>
    <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>

<input type="text" data-ng-model="employeeFilter.$" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter search results" />

<tr data-ng-repeat="employeeEntity in employees | filter:employeeFilter | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
    <td><a href="#/employee-details/{{employeeEntity.EmployeeNumber}}">{{ employeeEntity.EmployeeNumber }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ employeeEntity.EmployeeName }}</td>
    <td>{{ employeeEntity.SupervisorEmployeeName }}</td>
    <td>{{ employeeEntity.DepartmentName }}</td>
    <td>{{ employeeEntity.EmployeeStatusName }}</td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible, out of the box, to apply strict criteria to only one column of data?

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably going to have write your own comparator which should only be a few lines long.

Comment: Ok. That is what I thought, just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something. Thanks.

Comment: on the other hand for small collections you can run your strict filter first and then filter the rest on a second round, but make sure your collections are not big otherwise you might blow your performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution from user maxisam here:

[Filtering by Multiple Specific Model Properties in AngularJS (in OR relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship)

In my controller, I placed the following:

```
$scope.filterEmployees = function (row) {
    var filterValue = $scope.searchFilter;
    var returnValue = true;
    if (filterValue !== undefined) {
        var supervisorName = row.SupervisorEmployeeName == null ? '' : row.SupervisorEmployeeName;
        var employeeName = row.EmployeeName == null ? '' : row.EmployeeName;
        var departmentName = row.DepartmentName == null ? '' : row.DepartmentName;
        returnValue =
        (
            angular.lowercase(employeeName).indexOf(angular.lowercase(filterValue)) !== -1 ||
            angular.lowercase(supervisorName).indexOf(angular.lowercase(filterValue)) !== -1 ||
            angular.lowercase(departmentName).indexOf(angular.lowercase(filterValue)) !== -1
        );
    }
    return returnValue;
};
```

In my search view I have this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 250px; float: left">
        <a href="#/employee-post/0" class="btn btn-success">New Employee</a>
        <select data-ng-model="statusFilter" class="form-control">
            <option selected="selected" value="Active">Active</option>
            <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    Search results: {{employees.length == null ? '0' : (employees | filter:employeeFilter).length}} items
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 250px; float: right">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-default">Filter</span>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="searchFilter" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter search results" />
    </div>
</div>

 <tr data-ng-repeat="employeeEntity in employees | filter:filterEmployees | filter: { 'EmployeeStatusName' : statusFilter }: true | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
    <td><a href="#/employee-details/{{employeeEntity.EmployeeNumber}}">{{ employeeEntity.EmployeeNumber }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ employeeEntity.EmployeeName }}</td>
    <td>{{ employeeEntity.SupervisorEmployeeName }}</td>
    <td>{{ employeeEntity.DepartmentName }}</td>
    <td>{{ employeeEntity.EmployeeStatusName }}</td>
</tr>
```

The EmployeeStatusName filter is now based on strict filtering while everything else is evaluated using a wildcard. I'd like to make this more universal but at least this works.