# AngularJS filter with nested objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I'm trying to create a list with the menu items for a food court. I want to filter out my list based on the search from the input box. But with AngularJS default filter it is not applying the filter on each of the value that is present in the list. Like for example from the results populated I'm able to filter it out based on Item name(like with keywords Idly, Dosa) and also with price, but not with foodcourt name, vendor name(i.e kamath) and with foodtype (i.e breakfast,lunch,dinner).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="fcApp" ng-controller="fcController">
    <div class="control">
        <input type="search" ng-model="txtSearch" placeholder="search here"/>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div ng-repeat="foodCourt in fcMenu" >

            <div ng-repeat="vendor in foodCourt.foodCourtDetails">

                <div ng-repeat="foodType in vendor.vendorDetails">
                    <div class="foodItem" ng-repeat="foodDetails in foodType.foodItemDetails | filter:txtSearch">
                            <div>{{foodDetails.itemName}} - {{foodType.foodTypeName}}</div>
                            <div>{{vendor.vendorName}} - {{foodCourt.foodCourtName}}</div>
                            <div>{{foodDetails.itemPrice}}</div>             
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}body{background:#000;color:#fff;}
.control{display:block;margin:10px 0;}
.control input{width:100% !important;box-sizing:border-box;}
input[type="search"]{width:inherit;padding:0.7em 0.5em;}
.foodItem{border:2px solid #CCC;border-radius:6px;margin:5px 0;}
```

Javascript:

```
var fcJSON = '[{"foodCourtName":"FoodCourt1","foodCourtDetails":[{"vendorName":"Adigas","vendorDetails":[{"foodTypeName":"Breakfast","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Idly - 2 Nos","itemDesc":"Idly - 2 Nos","itemPrice":" Rs. 20.00 ","itemComposition":"60gms each + 80 ml Chutney & 100 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Idly - vada ( 1 Idly + I vada )","itemDesc":"( 1 Idly + I vada )","itemPrice":" Rs. 25.00 ","itemComposition":"60 gms each piece+ 80 ml Chutney & 100 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Idly - vada ( 2 Idly + I vada )","itemDesc":"( 2 Idly + I vada )","itemPrice":" Rs. 35.00 ","itemComposition":"60 gms each piece+ 80 ml Chutney & 100 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Dosa - Plain","itemDesc":"Dosa - Plain","itemPrice":" Rs. 25.00 ","itemComposition":"80 gms + 60 ml Chutney & 80 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Dosa","itemDesc":"Masala/Onion / Rawa / Ragi / Vegetable / Wheat /Neer /GHEE ROST","itemPrice":" Rs. 32.00 ","itemComposition":"150 gms + 80 ml Chutney & 80 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"SPL Dosa","itemDesc":"GHEE MASALA/Rava masala","itemPrice":" Rs. 37.00 ","itemComposition":"150 gm + 80 ml Chutney & 80 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Sweet -","itemDesc":"Sweet - Payasam / Jalebi / Ladoo / Gulab Jamun / Mysore Pak / Burfi / etc","itemPrice":" Rs. 10.00 ","itemComposition":"80 ml / 35 gms","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Veg pulao","itemDesc":"Veg pulao","itemPrice":" Rs. 34.00 ","itemComposition":"250 gms rice +100 gms Raita ","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Mini Meal (South)","itemDesc":"Mini Meal (South)","itemPrice":" Rs. 45.00 ","itemComposition":"2 Chapathi+200grmRice +90ml Rasam+90ml Sambhar+90ml veg curry","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"South Indian MEAL","itemDesc":"VEGETARIAN. MEAL","itemPrice":" Rs. 60.00 ","itemComposition":"2 Chapathi+100grmRice +100grm rice bath+90mlRasam+90grmDry veg preperation+90ml grave veg preperation+90mlSambhar/dal+Curd+Pappad+sweet","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"NORTH INDIAN VEG. MEAL","itemDesc":"NORTH INDIAN VEG. MEAL","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"1 Chapathi+1 Tanduri roti+100 grm biryani +100grm rice+90 ml Rasam+90grm veg dry +90ml curry+90 ml dal+Curd+Pappad+swet","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"NORTH KARNATAKA MEAL","itemDesc":"PLANTAIAN LEAF MEAL","itemPrice":" Rs. 95.00 ","itemComposition":"JOWA ROTI+ENNAGAI+KALU PALLYA+SOPPU PALLYA+RICE+SAMBAR+BAJJI+KOSAMBARI/CHATNI+BUTTER MILK+CURD+SALAD+SWEET","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]},{"foodTypeName":"Snacks","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Idly - 2 Nos","itemDesc":"Idly - 2 Nos","itemPrice":" Rs. 20.00 ","itemComposition":"60gms each + 80 ml Chutney & 100 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Idly - vada ( 1 Idly + I vada )","itemDesc":"( 1 Idly + I vada )","itemPrice":" Rs. 25.00 ","itemComposition":"60 gms each piece+ 80 ml Chutney & 100 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Idly - vada ( 2 Idly + I vada )","itemDesc":"( 2 Idly + I vada )","itemPrice":" Rs. 35.00 ","itemComposition":"60 gms each piece+ 80 ml Chutney & 100 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Rava Idly - 2 Nos","itemDesc":"Rava Idly - 2 Nos","itemPrice":" Rs. 32.00 ","itemComposition":"60 gms each + 80 ml Chutney & 100 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Dosa - Plain","itemDesc":"Dosa - Plain","itemPrice":" Rs. 25.00 ","itemComposition":"80 gms + 60 ml Chutney & 80 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Dosa","itemDesc":"Masala/Onion / Rawa / Ragi / Vegetable / Wheat /Neer /GHEE ROST","itemPrice":" Rs. 32.00 ","itemComposition":"150 gms + 80 ml Chutney & 80 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"SPL Dosa","itemDesc":"GHEE MASALA/Rava masala","itemPrice":" Rs. 37.00 ","itemComposition":"150 gm + 80 ml Chutney & 80 ml Sambar","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Dosa - Set","itemDesc":"3 NO","itemPrice":" Rs. 32.00 ","itemComposition":"60 gms each + 80 ml Chutney & 100 gms SAGU","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Uthappam","itemDesc":"Masala / Tomato / Onion / other","itemPrice":" Rs. 32.00 ","itemComposition":"200 gms + 80 ml Chutney & 80 ml SAGU","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Vada Single","itemDesc":"Vada","itemPrice":" Rs. 17.00 ","itemComposition":"60GRMS +60 ML CHATNI+80ML SAMBAR","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Chow Chow Bath","itemDesc":"Chow Chow Bath","itemPrice":" Rs. 35.00 ","itemComposition":"120 gms each of Khara & 100 gms Kesari + 60 ml Chutney","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Khara Bath - Upma","itemDesc":"Khara Bath - Upma","itemPrice":" Rs. 20.00 ","itemComposition":"120 gms + Chutney ","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Pongal","itemDesc":"Pongal","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"250 gms + 60 ml Chutney + 80 ml Raita ","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"}]}]}]},{"foodCourtName":"FoodCourt2","foodCourtDetails":[{"vendorName":"Dolphin","vendorDetails":[{"foodTypeName":"Breakfast","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Masala Chaas","itemDesc":"Spicy butter milk, cold","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of masala butter milk","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]},{"foodTypeName":"Lunch","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Masala Chaas","itemDesc":"Spicy butter milk, cold","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of masala butter milk","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Lassi","itemDesc":"Sweet curd","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of sweet lassi","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Amritsari Kheer","itemDesc":"Rice kheer ","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"110 ml of Rice Kheer","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle paranthas","itemDesc":"Cholle 3 paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 3 Tandoori paranthas (60 grams Each)+ Raita 85 ml.","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"cholle kulchas","itemDesc":"cholle stuffed 2 aloo kulchas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 2 Kulchas (60 grams Each)+ Salad 85 ml+ Imli chutney 80 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle rice ","itemDesc":"cholle, Jeera basmathi rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 200 grams Basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Dal rice","itemDesc":"Dal, basmathi rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams Dal+200 grams basmathi rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Dal paranthas","itemDesc":"Dal, 3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams dal+ 3 Tandoori paranthas+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"butter paneer paranthas","itemDesc":"butter paneer gravy, 3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams butter paneer gravy+ 4 pieces of paneer+ 3 tandoori paranthas+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"butter paneer rice","itemDesc":"butter paneer gravy, basmathi jeera rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams butter paneer gravy+ 4 pieces of paneer+ 200 grams of basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Kadi Pakoda rice","itemDesc":"Kadi pakoda, basmathi jeera rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams Kadi pakoda+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+Raita 85 ml.","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Rajma parantha","itemDesc":"Rajma ,3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 Rajma+ 3 tandoori paranthas(60 grams each)+60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Rajma rice","itemDesc":"Rajma, basmathi jeera rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams rajma+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Butter chicken rice","itemDesc":"Butter chicken, 3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"120 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Butter chicken paranthas ","itemDesc":"Butter chicken, 3 tandoori paranthas ","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"120 grams chicken+ 3 tandoori paranthas (60 grams each)+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Chicken Curry paranthas ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry,3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+ 3 tandoori paranthas (60 grams each)+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Chicken curry rice ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry, basmathi jeers rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]},{"foodTypeName":"Snacks","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Masala Chaas","itemDesc":"Spicy butter milk, cold","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of masala butter milk","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Lassi","itemDesc":"Sweet curd","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of sweet lassi","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Amritsari Kheer","itemDesc":"Rice kheer ","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"110 ml of Rice Kheer","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle paranthas","itemDesc":"Cholle 3 paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 3 Tandoori paranthas (60 grams Each)+ Raita 85 ml.","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"cholle kulchas","itemDesc":"cholle stuffed 2 aloo kulchas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 2 Kulchas (60 grams Each)+ Salad 85 ml+ Imli chutney 80 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle rice ","itemDesc":"cholle, Jeera basmathi rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 200 grams Basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Chicken Curry paranthas ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry,3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+ 3 tandoori paranthas (60 grams each)+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Chicken curry rice ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry, basmathi jeers rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]},{"foodTypeName":"Dinner","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Masala Chaas","itemDesc":"Spicy butter milk, cold","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of masala butter milk","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Lassi","itemDesc":"Sweet curd","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of sweet lassi","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Amritsari Kheer","itemDesc":"Rice kheer ","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"110 ml of Rice Kheer","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle paranthas","itemDesc":"Cholle 3 paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 3 Tandoori paranthas (60 grams Each)+ Raita 85 ml.","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"cholle kulchas","itemDesc":"cholle stuffed 2 aloo kulchas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 2 Kulchas (60 grams Each)+ Salad 85 ml+ Imli chutney 80 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle rice ","itemDesc":"cholle, Jeera basmathi rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 200 grams Basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Dal rice","itemDesc":"Dal, basmathi rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams Dal+200 grams basmathi rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Dal paranthas","itemDesc":"Dal, 3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams dal+ 3 Tandoori paranthas+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"butter paneer paranthas","itemDesc":"butter paneer gravy, 3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams butter paneer gravy+ 4 pieces of paneer+ 3 tandoori paranthas+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"butter paneer rice","itemDesc":"butter paneer gravy, basmathi jeera rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams butter paneer gravy+ 4 pieces of paneer+ 200 grams of basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Kadi Pakoda rice","itemDesc":"Kadi pakoda, basmathi jeera rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams Kadi pakoda+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+Raita 85 ml.","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Rajma parantha","itemDesc":"Rajma ,3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 Rajma+ 3 tandoori paranthas(60 grams each)+60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Rajma rice","itemDesc":"Rajma, basmathi jeera rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams rajma+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Butter chicken rice","itemDesc":"Butter chicken, 3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"120 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Butter chicken paranthas ","itemDesc":"Butter chicken, 3 tandoori paranthas ","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"120 grams chicken+ 3 tandoori paranthas (60 grams each)+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Chicken Curry paranthas ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry,3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+ 3 tandoori paranthas (60 grams each)+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Chicken curry rice ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry, basmathi jeers rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]}]}]},{"foodCourtName":"FoodCourt3","foodCourtDetails":[{"vendorName":"Aathapar","vendorDetails":[{"foodTypeName":"Breakfast","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Masala Chaas","itemDesc":"Spicy butter milk, cold","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of masala butter milk","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Lassi","itemDesc":"Sweet curd","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of sweet lassi","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Amritsari Kheer","itemDesc":"Rice kheer ","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"110 ml of Rice Kheer","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle paranthas","itemDesc":"Cholle 3 paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 3 Tandoori paranthas (60 grams Each)+ Raita 85 ml.","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"cholle kulchas","itemDesc":"cholle stuffed 2 aloo kulchas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 2 Kulchas (60 grams Each)+ Salad 85 ml+ Imli chutney 80 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle rice ","itemDesc":"cholle, Jeera basmathi rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 200 grams Basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Chicken Curry paranthas ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry,3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+ 3 tandoori paranthas (60 grams each)+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Chicken curry rice ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry, basmathi jeers rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]},{"foodTypeName":"Lunch","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Chicken curry rice ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry, basmathi jeers rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]},{"foodTypeName":"Snacks","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Masala Chaas","itemDesc":"Spicy butter milk, cold","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of masala butter milk","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Lassi","itemDesc":"Sweet curd","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of sweet lassi","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Amritsari Kheer","itemDesc":"Rice kheer ","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"110 ml of Rice Kheer","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle paranthas","itemDesc":"Cholle 3 paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 3 Tandoori paranthas (60 grams Each)+ Raita 85 ml.","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"cholle kulchas","itemDesc":"cholle stuffed 2 aloo kulchas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 2 Kulchas (60 grams Each)+ Salad 85 ml+ Imli chutney 80 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle rice ","itemDesc":"cholle, Jeera basmathi rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 200 grams Basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Chicken Curry paranthas ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry,3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+ 3 tandoori paranthas (60 grams each)+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Chicken curry rice ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry, basmathi jeers rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]},{"foodTypeName":"Dinner","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Masala Chaas","itemDesc":"Spicy butter milk, cold","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of masala butter milk","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Chicken Curry paranthas ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry,3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+ 3 tandoori paranthas (60 grams each)+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Chicken curry rice ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry, basmathi jeers rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]}]},{"vendorName":"Tadka Singh","vendorDetails":[{"foodTypeName":"Breakfast","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Masala Chaas","itemDesc":"Spicy butter milk, cold","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of masala butter milk","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Lassi","itemDesc":"Sweet curd","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of sweet lassi","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Amritsari Kheer","itemDesc":"Rice kheer ","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"110 ml of Rice Kheer","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"TRUE"},{"itemName":"Cholle paranthas","itemDesc":"Cholle 3 paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 3 Tandoori paranthas (60 grams Each)+ Raita 85 ml.","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"cholle kulchas","itemDesc":"cholle stuffed 2 aloo kulchas","itemPrice":" Rs. 80.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 2 Kulchas (60 grams Each)+ Salad 85 ml+ Imli chutney 80 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Cholle rice ","itemDesc":"cholle, Jeera basmathi rice","itemPrice":" Rs. 70.00 ","itemComposition":"160 grams cholle+ 200 grams Basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Chicken Curry paranthas ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry,3 tandoori paranthas","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+ 3 tandoori paranthas (60 grams each)+ 60 grams salad","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Chicken curry rice ","itemDesc":"Chicken curry, basmathi jeers rice.","itemPrice":" Rs. 90.00 ","itemComposition":"130 grams chicken+200 grams basmathi jeera rice+ raita 85 ml","isVegetarian":"FALSE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]},{"foodTypeName":"Lunch","foodItemDetails":[{"itemName":"Masala Chaas","itemDesc":"Spicy butter milk, cold","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of masala butter milk","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"},{"itemName":"Lassi","itemDesc":"Sweet curd","itemPrice":" Rs. 30.00 ","itemComposition":"320 ml of sweet lassi","isVegetarian":"TRUE","isSpecial":"FALSE"}]}]}]}]';

var app = angular.module('fcApp', []);
app.controller('fcController', function ($scope) {
$scope.fcMenu = eval('(' + fcJSON + ')');
});
```

How should i apply a filter so that i should be able to apply filter on all the items in the list (i.e itemname, foodtype, vendor, foodcourt and price?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope something like below can help you resolve your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship

Comment: So, do you want to display all the vendors, fooditems etc in the food court if the search text matches the foodcourt?  I think that is going to require a custom filter, examining each object recursively.  I'll try to write an example when I get a chance

Comment: @Beartums Yes, If the search matches any of the itemName/foodTypeName/vendorName/foodCourtName/itemPrice from the list, the respective items only should be populated in the list after filter. 

Any good article that will help me to create a custom filter?

Comment: @manju, [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beartums/j3kssdkL/3/) almost does what you want.  The problem is that the logic for each level actually is: "Include this item if any of its descendants have the search text OR if any of its ancestors have the search text".  That's pretty difficult without flattening the data.  You will notice in th filter that I've written that an item's sibling are also included even if they don't have the search text.  That's because my filter includes the object (and all subObjs) is the text is found anywhere in it.  Choose one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom filter **"myFilter"** as below:
JSFiddle Link For Reference - https://jsfiddle.net/bz5zon4L/#

```
 <div ng-controller="fcController">
    <div class="control">
      <input type="search" ng-model="txtSearch" placeholder="search here" />
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <div ng-repeat="foodCourt in fcMenu">

        <div ng-repeat="vendor in foodCourt.foodCourtDetails">

          <div ng-repeat="foodType in vendor.vendorDetails">
            <div class="foodItem" ng-repeat="foodDetails in foodType.foodItemDetails | myFilter:txtSearch:foodType:vendor:foodCourt">
              <div>{{foodDetails.itemName}} - {{foodType.foodTypeName}}</div>
              <div>{{vendor.vendorName}} - {{foodCourt.foodCourtName}}</div>
              <div>{{foodDetails.itemPrice}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

app.filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(item, textSearch, foodType, vendor, foodCourt) {
        var result = [];
        if (textSearch && item && foodType && vendor && foodCourt) {
            for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                var tempSearch = item[i].itemName + foodType.foodTypeName + vendor.vendorName + foodCourt.foodCourtName + item[i].itemPrice;
                if (tempSearch) {
                    var searchIndex = tempSearch.toLowerCase().search(textSearch.toLowerCase());
                    if (searchIndex >= 0) {
                        result.push(item[i]);
                        tempSearch = '';
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        return item;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm kind of trying to understand  what is the concept of using 'return' keyword before function(item, textSearch,foodType,vendor,foodcourt). I think u have used closure. I'm just trying to understand when should we return functions within the call back functions.  Is it a way to trigger the function within a function? Can you help me in understanding the concept.

Answer (score 0):

For that First of all,You have to convert your **Hierarchical Data** into **Flat Data**
like :

```
 {"foodCourtName":"FoodCourt1","vendorName":"Adigas","foodTypeName":"Breakfast",..}
```

You can do that in JS like:

```
    var flatData=[];

    for (var i = 0; i < fcJSON.length; i++) {

    var flatDataObj=new Object();

    flatDataObj.foodCourtName=fcJSON.foodCourtName;

    if (fcJSON[i].foodCourtDetails) {

    flatDataObj.vendorName=fcJSON[i].foodCourtDetails.vendorName;

    }

    if (fcJSON[i].foodCourtDetails.vendorDetails) {

    flatDataObj.foodTypeName=fcJSON[i].foodCourtDetails.vendorDetails.foodTypeName;

    }

    //nd so on....

    flatData.push(flatDataObj);
    }
```

Now you can provide filters and filter data using Angular [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 0):

There are many good pointers and answers here.There may be another way to achieve what you desire with an added advantage.As you can see there are two solutions proposed,

- Add an custom filter
- Flatten your data

Alternative to these solutions can be achieved with a little change in your UI. You can let users refine their search of the data with multiple search boxes [one for each level] or let them choose the category that they want to search using a dropdown.

```
<div ng-repeat="foodCourt in fcMenu | filter:foodCourtSearch">
    <div ng-repeat="vendor in foodCourt.foodCourtDetails | filter:vendorSearch">
      <div ng-repeat="foodType in vendor.vendorDetails">
        <div class="foodItem" ng-repeat="foodDetails in foodType.foodItemDetails | filter:foodItemSearch">
```

[Plunker Demo for multiple search boxes](https://plnkr.co/edit/0bPlmIeSp4fZyszn4EvW)

A single omni box might be your requirement,but this is one way to tackle the problem.Having multiple search boxes will help users to refine their search (Like whether lunch is available in foodcourt1) which cannot be done with single search box.

**P.S: important** Using **eval** is not a good practice,use `angular.fromJson(fcJSON);` instead.